# Inserir no banco de dados mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo um *site* que tem um campo de *login*, que ao logar leva ao setor de administrador podendo inserir, excluir e alterar itens do banco de dados. Já a página de cadastro não está inserindo no banco de dados. Na verdade, ela não está realizando função alguma que deveria realizar. Deveria não permitir o cadastro se as senhas não batessem, deveria não permitir caso algum campo faltasse, e se tudo estivesse certo, deveria simplesmente cadastrar e levar a tela de *login*.

Poderiam me ajudar? Aqui vai os códigos:

```
<body>
    <div class="container container-twelve">
        <div class="four columns offset-by-four">
            <h1 class="titles">Cadastro</h1>
            <?php if(isset($_SESSION["success"])) {?>
            <p><?= $_SESSION["success"] ?></p>
        <?php }?>
        <?php unset($_SESSION["success"]); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="four columns offset-by-four" id ="login">
            <form action="cadastra_usuario.php"  method="post">
                <label for="nome">Nome</label>
                <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Digite seu nome">
                <label for="email">Email de usuário </label>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Seu email para login">
                <label for="senha">Senha</label>
                <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Sua senha">
                <label for="senha2">Repita sua senha</label>
                <input type="password" name="senha2" placeholder="Repita sua senha">
                <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
            </form>

            <p><a href="index.php"> << Voltar para o site</a></p>
            <p><a href="login.php"> Já tenho um cadastro >> </a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

cadastra_usuario.php:
<?php 
    include('conecta.php');
    include('functions.php');
    include('function_usuario.php');

    $senha = $_POST['senha'];
    $senha2 = $_POST['senha2'];

    $cadastra = cadastraUsuario($_POST['nome'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['senha']);

    if($senha != $senha2){
        $_SESSION["danger"] = "As senhas não conferem!";
        header("Location: cadastro.php");
    }
    if($cadastra == null){
        $_SESSION["danger"] = "Complete todos os campos!";
        header("Location: cadastro.php");
    } else {
        $_SESSION["success"] = "Usuário cadastrado com sucesso.";
        header("Location: login.php");
    }
?>
```

E a função:

```
function cadastraUsuario($conexao, $nome, $email, $senha){
        $query = "insert into usuarios (nome, email, senha) values ('{$nome}', '{$email}', '{$senha}')";
        return mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
    }
```

Caso precisem dos códigos completos, me peçam por favor.

Comment: Parece que você deveria chamar a função `cadastraUsuario()` depois das validações e não antes.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, chamei eles na função ao invés do arquivo, e tudo deu certo. Obrigado !

Comment: @Gabriel aqui não editamos o título da pergunta para "resolvido" quando encontramos uma resposta. Aqui temos que marcar uma resposta como a correta ou poste uma nova resposta e marque-a como correta, leia mais aqui [tour] e aqui [ask]

Comment: Editei a pergunta porque "phpmyadmin" não é um "banco de dados", leia isto pra entender as diferenças: [Qual a diferença entre o mysql e o phpmyadmin?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115692/3635)

Answer (score 1):

Você está incluindo o usuário e depois validando as informações.

Como o amigo disse nos comentários, chame a função **cadastraUsuario()** após a verificação

```
<?php 
    include('conecta.php');
    include('functions.php');
    include('function_usuario.php');

    $senha = $_POST['senha'];
    $senha2 = $_POST['senha2'];

    if($senha != $senha2){
        $_SESSION["danger"] = "As senhas não conferem!";
        header("Location: cadastro.php");
    }

    $cadastra = cadastraUsuario($_POST['nome'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['senha']);

    if($cadastra == null){
        $_SESSION["danger"] = "Complete todos os campos!";
        header("Location: cadastro.php");
    } else {
        $_SESSION["success"] = "Usuário cadastrado com sucesso.";
        header("Location: login.php");
    }


?>
```

Uma coisa que não pude deixar de notar é que você está deixando o erro de banco validas seus dados (conclui isso pois você usou o retorno do *insert* para saber se o registro foi incluído). Ok, mas eu não varia assim. Se eu puder te sugerir, faça assim:

```
<?php 
        include('conecta.php');
        include('functions.php');
        include('function_usuario.php');

        $senha = $_POST['senha'];
        $senha2 = $_POST['senha2'];
        $nome = $_POST['nome'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];         
        $validacaoOK = true;

        if($senha != $senha2){
            $_SESSION["danger"] = "As senhas não conferem!";
            header("Location: cadastro.php");
        }

        // Valide o resto dos dados sempre junto com **$validacaoOK**       

        if ($validacaoOK) {
          $cadastra = cadastraUsuario($nome, $email, $senha);

          if($cadastra == null){
            $_SESSION["danger"] = "Complete todos os campos!";
            header("Location: cadastro.php");
          } 
        }else {
            $_SESSION["success"] = "Usuário cadastrado com sucesso.";
            header("Location: login.php");
        }


    ?>
```

P.S.: Não programo em PHP, mas o caminho seria esse ai.