# Qual a diferença entre o MySQL e o phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Qual a diferença entre o MySQL e o phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

### O que é o MySQL?

O MySQL é um servidor que funciona por TCP, mas não por HTTP, em instalações como Xampp e Wamp ele não esta ligado diretamente ao Apache ou PHP, ele na verdade é um **servidor de *banco de dados*** totalmente separado que pode ser instalado até em um computador diferente de uma mesma rede ou de uma rede externa que seja acessível e fica em uma porta diferente do HTTP.

Ele **não tem navegação de pastas** igual aos servidores HTTP ele fica em uma porta diferente, enquanto Apache, Ngnix, Lighttpd ficam geralmente em portas como 80, 8000, 8080, 9000, já o MySQL na maioria das vezes fica na porta 3306.

Quando linguagens dinâmicas ou softwares acessam o MySQL ele na verdade apenas enviam "comandos" para o servidor mysql via TCP, semelhante aos comandos de "terminal" (é possível instalar o mysql em uma maquina e usar como cliente pra acessar um servidor MySQL, podendo estar na mesma maquina ou não).

### O que é phpMyAdmin?

O phpMyAdmin não é um servidor, ele é um "gerenciador" escrito em [php](/questions/tagged/php) e [html](/questions/tagged/html), ou seja, ele é uma aplicação e não deve ser usado por outras aplicações acessíveis a outros usuários, ele é uma ferramenta que deve ser usada apenas pelo administrador do banco de dados e por vezes por quem mantem os scripts (por exemplo PHP), ele não é parte do MySQL, ele não é um banco dados, ele apenas é uma ferramenta pra facilitar a gestão do banco de dados e existem alternativas pra ele.

Aplicações como PHP **não se conectam** a ele, ele é uma aplicação que roda junto ao Apache e PHP e a única relação com o MySQL é que ele (o phpMyAdmin) se conecta ao MySQL na hora de executar *QUERIES*, assim como uma página de web normal que usa banco de dados.

Como o próprio site diz https://www.phpmyadmin.net/:

> *A tool written in PHP intended to handle the administration of MySQL over the WWW.*
>
> traduzindo:
> *É uma ferramenta escrita em PHP destinada a lidar com a administração do MySQL sobre o WWW.*

---

### Extra:

Para saber a diferença do Xampp, Wamp, EasyPHP leia a seguinte pergunta:

- [Qual diferença do Xampp, Wamp, EasyPHP, Zwamp e PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115689/3635)

Comment: Nem irei responder, essa resposta já é o suficiente!

Comment: Acho que o [Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench) é bem mais poderoso.

Comment: @JorgeB. Com toda certeza :D ... o problema é que a ultima versão pra windows esta bugada, já faz uns 4 meses :/ ... To usando o HeideSql, muito bom também

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento usa linux :D