# Gravar Varios Numeros Em Um Campo No Banco De Dados

Tags: php, mysql

Galera eu tenho uma coluna numa tabela no banco de dados que se chama "sincroniza" dentro dela eu quero salvar varios numeros separados por virgula, e depois fazer uma verificação em uma pagina da seguinte forma, que se existir entre aquelas virgulas um numero que seja igual ao numero passado na URL ele faça uma função pra mim, de qual forma eu consigo incrementar um numero novo com a virgula nessa campo "sincroniza" e como eu faço para verificar entre as virgulas se esse numero é igual ao passado na URL?? Obrigado des de já

Comment: Editei a pergunta porque "phpmyadmin" não é um "banco de dados", leia isto pra entender as diferenças: [Qual a diferença entre o mysql e o phpmyadmin?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115692/3635)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize campo formato JSON.

MySQL da suporte para formato JSON, que é perfeito para seu intuito.

Basicamente:

Você irá capturar os números, colocar em um array e converter para JSON, após isso irá salvar no banco.

```
$numbers = [1,2,3];
$json = json_encode($numbers);
// save to db
```

Basicamente. MySQL da suporte nativo para field json, como você pode consultar na documentação:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html

Após salvar, basta executar as querys com `JSON_CONTAINS` para verificar se o número informado esta presente no campo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja exemplo de uma query com o `JSON_CONTAINS`

Primeiro criei um json e depois perguntei se o número `3` estava presente no json.

Consulte a documentação, implementação será fácil.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente você deve criar uma coluna que suporte texto. Apesar de serem vários números, da forma que você quer armazenar, é impossível utilizar um campo númerico.

```
  CREATE TABLE xxx (
        ....
        sincrozina VARCHAR(255) //defina o tamanho necessário
        ....);
```

Se você quer adicionar um valor nesse campo, é necessário que exista um registro(como você vai criar isso, eu não sei). Para incrementar o campo com um valor, utilize a seguinte SQL.

```
 UPDATE xxx SET sincroinza = CONCAT(sincroinza, ",", novo_número) WHERE ....
```

`novo_numero`é o novo valor que você quer inserir. Para checar se determinado número está nessa lista, você deve fazer da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE sincroniza LIKE %numero_buscado%
```

Onde `numero_buscado` é o número que você quer verificar. Se esta query retornar o registro onde está a lista de números, é por que o valor está na lista.

Postei apenas trechos de SQL. Como você não forneceu nenhum código, e poucos informações, não tem como te ajudar com outros detalhes da implementação, então você vai ter que adaptar essas SQLs ao teu código, para chegar a solução.

Comment: Só sei que nesse select se ele buscar por 1 e tiver 10 por exemplo, irá retornar né! Mas de resto pode até ajudar, tente arrumar essa parte!

Comment: Verdade, não tinha percebido este detalhe. Deveria ser: like  %,n or like %n, or  = n