# MySQL fazer consulta e distinguir maiúsculas de minúsculas

Tags: php, mysql

Queria que o meu `login.php` verificasse se a password tem maiúsculas, porque quando existem, ele reconhece, pois tenho a minha base de dados com o collation `utf8_general_ci`. Já tentei por o collation em `utf8_bin` e `latin1_general_cs` mas reconhecem letras maiúsculas como minúsculas. 
Query em `php`:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$password = $_POST['pw'];

$consulta = mysql_query("SELECT id,password,tipo_ut FROM utilizador WHERE id ='".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."' AND password = '".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."' LIMIT 1");
```

Alguém tem uma outra sugestão? E haverá algum problema alterar uma base de dados inteira de `utf8_general_ci` para outro qualquer?

Comment: Editei a pergunta porque "phpmyadmin" não é um "banco de dados", leia isto pra entender as diferenças: [Qual a diferença entre o mysql e o phpmyadmin?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115692/3635)

Comment: Perfeito mas pra diferenciar minusculas de maiusculas coloca também no login caso a entrada contenha login e senha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode fazer essa verificação em php antes. Para fazer comparação entre strings na DB MySql aqui está esta maneira simples:

EX:

```
select 'Miguel' LIKE BINARY 'miguel'; // diferente
select 'Miguel' LIKE 'miguel'; // igual
```

Ou seja:

```
mysql_query("SELECT id,password,tipo_ut FROM utilizador WHERE id ='".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."' AND BINARY password = '".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."' LIMIT 1");
```

Mas no seu contexto e se percebi bem o meu conselho é fazer logo no `login.php`:

```
$temMaiusculas = preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $password); // 1 (true, tem maiusculas) ou 0 (false, não tem)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adicionei `BINARY` na query, e funcionou. 
Resultado:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$password = $_POST['pw'];

$consulta = mysql_query("SELECT id,password,tipo_ut FROM utilizador WHERE id ='".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."' AND BINARY password = '".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."' LIMIT 1");
```

Obrigado pela dica vlw.

Answer (score 0):

Por uma questão de performance coloque o BINARY depois do igual, exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM temp1 WHERE col1 = BINARY "ABC" AND col2 = "DEF" ;
```

Para o seu código:

```
$consulta = mysql_query("SELECT id,password,tipo_ut FROM utilizador WHERE id ='".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."' AND password = BINARY '".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."' LIMIT 1");
```