# Erro ao criar chave estrangeira MySql no phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, chave-estrangeira

Estou tendo problemas para criar chaves estrangeiras no `mysql` através do `phpmyadmin`.

Tenho estas tabelas

```
CREATE TABLE `cidade` (
`idCidade` int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nome` varchar(25),
`Uf` CHAR(2)
);

CREATE TABLE `aeroporto` (
`idAeroporto` int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nome` varchar(100),
`endereco` varchar(200),
`idCidade` integer
);
```

Mas quando tento criar a relação

```
ALTER TABLE `usuario` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_cidadeUsuario` FOREIGN KEY (`idCidade`)
REFERENCES `cidade` (`idCidade`);
```

tenho o seguinte erro:

```
 #1005 - Can't create table `trab_tsnet_142`.`#sql-1a80_281` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

O que pode estar acontecendo?

(obs: essa é só uma das relações que esta dando erro, tenho o mesmo problema em outras relações).

Comment: Editei a pergunta porque "phpmyadmin" não é um "banco de dados", leia isto pra entender as diferenças: [Qual a diferença entre o mysql e o phpmyadmin?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115692/3635)

Comment: Pra ajudar quem está com esse erro mesmo os tipos sendo iguais. Isso pode acontecer se na hora de criar o banco ou as tabelas a engine padrão foi deixada como o MyIsam, pra resolver é só recriar a tabela e adicionar em baixo entre o fecha parenteses e o ponto e virgula: "ENGINE=InnoDB", o innodb é a engine que faz o relacionamento entre tabelas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verifique se os campos que você está tentando referenciar são exatamente do mesmo tipo e tamanho. O que também pode estar acontecendo é que para adicionar um campo elegível para chave estrangeira pelo phpmyadmin, você terá primeiro que transformá-lo em índice. Após transformar em índice, procure a opção `Ver relações`, na estrutura da tabela e adicione a foreign key. Não sei se depende da versão do phpmyadmin, mas o caminho é algo parecido como: `clique no BD -> Tabela -> Estrutura -> Ver Relações (fica ao lado de "Visualização para impressão").`

Comment: Valeu pela resposta, realmente como você disse estava tentando relacionar índices de tipos diferentes. Obrigado pela ajuda.