# Problema com mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de saber o que posso fazer para o `mysql` reconhecer o caractere "+", pois ele mostra em uma parte do meu site o nome com o "+" e quando faco uma requisição em `$_GET` preciso recuperar este nome pela `url` porem ele não reconhece o que eu poderia fazer para ele reconhecer o sinal de "+" na `url`?

Essa e a pagina antes de clicar no botão leia mais. ela esta chamando normal o nome.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora essa e a pagina quando clica no botao leia mais ele nao esta reconhecendo o sinal de "+", pois eu somente retirei ele e reconheceu o que poderia fazer para reconhece-lo?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Os acentos funcionam normalmente?

Comment: sim normalmente

Comment: opa consegui, achei uma função chamada `urlencode()` para quem estiver com o mesmo problema coloque essa função na `url` ex: `?codigo=urlencode($id)` antes da requisição da pagina.

Comment: Editei a pergunta porque "phpmyadmin" não é um "banco de dados", leia isto pra entender as diferenças: [Qual a diferença entre o mysql e o phpmyadmin?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115692/3635)

Answer (score 1):

Sei que o problema já foi resolvido mas vou deixar mais uma opção e *tentar* explicar a primeira.

**urlencode():**
Basicamente transforma espaços brancos em um sinal de soma `+`, é usada mais em campos de busca, de formulários. Caracteres especiais ficam `%seguido de dois dígitos`

**rawurlencode()**
Transforma espaços brancos em `%20` mas também transforma acentos, caracteres especiais em `%seguido de dois dígitos`.

**Exemplos**

Temos no server-side

```
echo "http://algumsite.com.br"
. "/categoria/" . rawurlencode("últimas notícias")
. "/busca?q=" . urlencode("situação do Brasil");
```

E o resultado no client-side é o segunte:

```
http://algumsite.com.br/categoria/%C3%BAtimas%20not%C3%ADcias/busca?q=situa%C3%A7%C3%A3o+do+Brasil
```

Basicamente é isso, se tiver mais alguma dúvida pode deixar nos comentários.

Comment: obg pela resposta

Comment: se a resposta ajudou, não esqueça do +1 ;)