# Como saber se a consulta no banco de dados foi realizada com sucesso?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um banco de dados com cadastro de pessoas, o nome do meu db e ***Cadastro***  e nele eu tenho uma tabela ***usuarios*** com quatro colunas ja preenchidas ***id, idade, nome e email*** [image: usuarios cadastrados]
eu estou desenvolvendo um sistema de busca de usuarios aqui esta a pagina de pesquisa

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="GET" >
            <input type="text" autocomplete="on" name="q" placeholder="Digite a sua pesquisa" />
            <input type="submit" value="Tecle Enter" />
        </form>
        <?php

            $host = 'localhost';
            $user = 'devel';
            $password = '********';
            $database = 'Cadastro';

            $connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or die("conexao die");
            $query = $_GET['q'];

            if(isset($query)){
                $consult = mysqli_query("SELECT nome FROM 'usuarios' WHERE 'nome' LIKE %q%", $connect);
                $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $consult );
                print_r($result);
            }

            else {
                echo 'nao foi encontrado nada';
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

mas eu nao estou recebendo retorno existe alguma maneira de saber se a consulta foi bem sucedida pois eu acho que o meu erro esta na query da `$consult` eu sou completamente leigo em **MySQL**

print do resultado no navegador [image: print do resultado no navegador]

Comment: lembrando eu estou querendo recuperar a coluna nome do meu db referente ao meu GET

Comment: Imprime 'nao foi encontrado nada'? O que imprime?

Comment: o parametro GET e enviado mas nao esta me imprimindo nada

Comment: É enviado como? Não imprime nada na página? Mostre como está a fazer, url de onde está a tentar retirar o parametro

Comment: coloquei um print na pergunta ve ai @Miguel

Comment: O que imprime? não imprime nada?

Comment: perai ai o certo nao seria post nao? ou nao tem nada haver post e get?

Comment: Neste caso está bem, é $_GET['q']... Mas não imprime nada? Faz lá `echo $_GET_['q'];`

Comment: o parametro GET ta imprimindo mas a consulta nao esta respondendo

Comment: Tenta por o parâmetro da conexão primeiro($connect,"SELECT .....)

Comment: e talvez, $consult="SELECT....."; $result=mysqli_query($connect,$consult); e ai $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); print_r($row);

Comment: tentei tambem agora e nada

Comment: Tenta essa última ateração, que mandei, nos coments..

Comment: agora retornou nao foi encontrado nada @MagicHat

Comment: @NikoBellic Hey bro, Funfou?

Comment: funfo vlw @MagicHat

Comment: Editei a pergunta porque "phpmyadmin" não é um "banco de dados", leia isto pra entender as diferenças: [Qual a diferença entre o mysql e o phpmyadmin?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115692/3635)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fazendo um mix das soluções...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="GET" >
            <input type="text" autocomplete="on" name="q" placeholder="Digite a sua pesquisa" />
            <input type="submit" value="Tecle Enter" />
        </form>
       <?php
        $nome = $_GET['q'];
        $host = 'localhost';
        $user = 'devel';
        $password = '********';
        $database = 'Cadastro';

       
        $connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or die("conexao die");
        mysqli_select_db($connect,'Cadastro');
        

        if(isset($nome)){
            $consult = 'SELECT nome FROM usuarios WHERE nome LIKE "%' .$nome. '%"';
            $result = mysqli_query($connect,$consult);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            print_r($row);
        }

        else {
            echo 'nao foi encontrado nada';
        }
        mysqli_close($connect); 
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ainda nada testei e nada

Comment: vê assim beloo...

Comment: ops muda $query, pra $nome...

Comment: cara agora finalmente me retornou um Array ( [nome] => joao )

Comment: Falta algo ou era só isso?

Comment: era isso mesmo mas eu qeria saber aonde foi que eu errei +1 valeu

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="GET" >
            <input type="text" autocomplete="on" name="q" placeholder="Digite a sua pesquisa" />
            <input type="submit" value="Tecle Enter" />
        </form>
        <?php

            $host = 'localhost';
            $user = 'devel';
            $password = '********';
            $database = 'Cadastro';

            $connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or die("conexao die");
            $query = $_GET['q'];

            if(isset($query)){
                $consult = mysqli_query("SELECT nome FROM 'usuarios' WHERE 'nome' LIKE '%".$query."%'", $connect);
                $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $consult );
                print_r($result);
            }

            else {
                echo 'nao foi encontrado nada';
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note que o LIKE estava incorreto, não passando a variável `q` corretamente

Comment: nao retornou nada @Andre Balil

Comment: Aparece alguma mensagem? Ou vem o array() zerado?

Answer (score 2):

Apesar de não recomendar essa maneira, devias usar [prepared statments](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), mas o erro é que não está mesmo a usar a variável que contém o valor do `$_GET['q']`. Tens de inserir na query o que estás a procurar faz assim:

```
<?php

        $host = 'localhost';
        $user = 'devel';
        $password = '********';
        $database = 'Cadastro';

        $connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or die("conexao die");

        if(isset($_GET['q'])){
            $consult = mysqli_query('SELECT nome FROM usuarios WHERE nome LIKE "%' .$_GET['q']. '%"', $connect);
            $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $consult );
            print_r($result);
        }

        else {
            echo 'nao foi encontrado nada';
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: agora retornou nao foi encontrado nada @Miguel

Comment: conseguir ja era erro de concatecnazacao rs

Comment: Sim, mas o teu `if(isset(...` como está, está sujeito a erro. podes testar fazendo `www.teusite.com?j=nome`, em vez de `?q=..`. Deves fazer a condição para o `$_GET['q']` e não para o `$nome`

Comment: verdade cara esta sujeito a erro mesmo @Miguel

Comment: como eu faco para resolver isso?

Comment: Conseguiste? @NikoBellic

Comment: sim eu adicionei um if($nome != NULL)

Comment: Ok, é isso @NikoBellic, é a mesma coisa