# MySQLdb - inserir valor de uma variavel no banco de dados

Tags: mysql, python

eu estou enfrentando problemas ao tentar inserir os valores de minhas variaveis no banco de dados eu estou tentando fazer do seguinte modo

```
import MySQLdb

id = 4
idade = 18
nome = 'cebolinha'
email = 'cebolinha@mail.com'

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","devel","********","Cadastro")
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = 'INSERT INTO usuarios(id, idade, nome email) VALUES (id, idade, nome, email)'
cursor.execute(sql)
cursor.fetchone()
db.commit()
db.close()
```

quando eu vou ver no banco de dados nao esta inserindo os valores das minhas variaveis e nem esta me retorna nenhum erro

[image]

agora quando eu executo o script dessa maneira esta funcionando

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","devel","********","Cadastro")
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = 'INSERT INTO usuarios(id, idade, nome email) VALUES (3, 17, "daniel", "daniel@mail.com")'
cursor.execute(sql)
cursor.fetchone()
db.commit()
db.close()
```

lembrando que eu estou usando o modulo MySQLdb do python

Comment: Editei a pergunta porque "phpmyadmin" não é um "banco de dados", leia isto pra entender as diferenças: [Qual a diferença entre o mysql e o phpmyadmin?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115692/3635)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa passar o valores das variáveis dentro do insert. Fazendo isto `VALUES (id, idade, nome, email)` você está passando os literais (`id`, `idade`, `nome`, `email`) e não os valores das variáveis.

Troque isto

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO usuarios(id, idade, nome, email) VALUES (id, idade, nome, email)'
```

para

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO usuarios(id, idade, nome, email) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)'

sql_data = (id, idade, nome, email)
```

E na hora de executar, faça

```
cursor.execute(sql, sql_data)
```

Comment: nao funcionou nao :(

Comment: Não acontece nada? Não gera nenhum erro?

Comment: me retorna esse erro *query = query % db.literal(args)*
**TypeError: not enough arguments for format string**

Comment: Tá faltando uma vírgula entre nome e email, editei a resposta.

Comment: Jbueno: ou a string é marcada como arguemtnos posicionais (%s,) e você usa uma sequência com os dados (tupla, lista, etc...) , OU você usa um dicionário e marca os valores por nome na string `" ... %(nome)s, %(idade)s ` - na sua resposta você tenta insrir os dados de um dicionário em marcações sequênciais. Isso nem teria como funcionar já que dicionários não preservam a ordem de inserção  dos pares de chave/valor.

Comment: Tens razão, eu acabei misturando as duas formas, faltou café (e atenção) nessa hora. Vou editar a resposta, obrigado por avisar @jsbueno

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente deve ter acontecido algum erro. Na chamada insert into, ta faltando uma virgula.
`sql = 'INSERT INTO usuarios(id, idade, nome email) VALUES (3, 17, "daniel", "daniel@mail.com")'`

E acho que é só colocar uma virgula entre nome e email