# problema ao inserir valor unicode em banco de dados

Tags: mysql, python

eu estou quebrando a cabeca com isso desde ontem ja fiz de tudo para inserir o valor em utf8 mas nao esta funcionando eo seguinte eu tenho esse codigo como exemplo

```
#!/usr/bin python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "devel", "********", "Ditados")
cursor = db.cursor()
# cursor.execute("SET NAMES utf8mb4;")
# cursor.execute("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;")
# cursor.execute("SET character_set_connection=utf8mb4;")

autor = u"Desconhecido"
string = u"João e o Pé de Feijão"

sql = "INSERT INTO textos(autor, texto) VALUES ('%s', '%s')" % (autor, string)
cursor.execute(sql)
cursor.fetchone()
db.commit()
db.close()
```

quando eu executo esse script acontece o seguuinte erro

```
Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xE3o e o...' for column 'texto' at row 1 cursor.execute(sql)
```

quando eu vou ver no banco de dados o texto esta do seguinte formato

[image]

o meu banco e scrit esta todo em UTF8

[image]

[image]

alguem poderia me ajudar a contornar este problema

Comment: Tenta usar o método `decode` veja: `string = "João e o Pé de Feijão".decode('utf8')`

Comment: existe a anotacao u no inicio da minha string referente a unicode eu quero converter para utf8 para inserir no meu banco de dados

Comment: @drmcarvalho agora me retornou **UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe3' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)**

Comment: Editei a pergunta porque "phpmyadmin" não é um "banco de dados", leia isto pra entender as diferenças: [Qual a diferença entre o mysql e o phpmyadmin?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115692/3635)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente colocar o argumento `charset='utf8'` quando se conectar. Tipo:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "devel", "********", "Ditados", charset='utf8')
```

Comment: vlw cara era isso mesmo vlw +1