# Nº registos no SQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Boas,

Estou com uma duvida em relação ao mostrar o numero de registos de uma determinada tabela.

```
 SELECT COUNT Nome FROM `tb_utilizador`
```

Quero depois mostrar o numero de registos numa tabela em php.

```
<?php

include("Config.php");

$sql = mysql_query("Select * From tb_utilizador");
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if($linhas == 0){

echo "Nada encontrado";
exit();
}
else{

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

$ID = $row["id"];

if($linhas %2 == 0){

$cor = "#F0F0F0";
}
else{

$cor = "#E2EFFE";
}

 echo "

<tr bgcolor=\"$cor\">
<td>&nbsp;$id</td>

</tr>";


}
}
?>
```

Comment: O que está a acontecer? está a dar algum erro?

Comment: No SQL dá está mensagem Mensagens do MySQL : Documentação

#1054 - Unknown column 'COUNT' in 'field list'

Comment: Editei a pergunta porque "phpmyadmin" não é um "banco de dados", leia isto pra entender as diferenças: [Qual a diferença entre o mysql e o phpmyadmin?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115692/3635)

Comment: Concordo com as respostas que você tem. Se quer contar os registros e ainda usá-los não vale a pena fazer duas querys para isso. Basta usar `mysql_num_rows`. A título de informação, o erro que você reportou é causado pela sintaxe errada da query que usa o COUNT. O correto seria:  `SELECT COUNT(Nome) FROM tb_utilizador`.

Answer (score 2):

Não vale a pena fazer duas vezes `mysql_query`. Faça:

```
include("Config.php");

$rows = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_utilizador") or die('Problema na query');
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($rows); // isto vai dar o número de linhas retornadas

if($num_rows > 0) {
    $linhas = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rows)) {
        if($linhas%2 == 0){
            $cor = "#F0F0F0";
        }
        else{
            $cor = "#E2EFFE";
        }
        echo '
        <tr bgcolor="' .$cor. '">
            <td>&nbsp;' .$row['id']. '</td>
        </tr>';
        $linhas ++;
    }
}
else {
    echo 'Nada encontrado';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar o mysql_num_rows().

`$total = mysql_num_rows($sql);
echo "Total: ".$total;`