# JOIN de 3 tabelas +1 tabela de junção JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Tenho um programa em java que retorna a listagem de utentes que têm uma consulta nesse dia, para isso construí uma base de dados que relacionasse alguns dados importantes dos utentes, o nome do médico com a qual vao ter uma consulta e ainda alguns dados como a sala e o piso. Para que a query SQL retorne apenas as consulta desse dia tentei fazer JOIN as 3 tabelas + a tabela de junção com um WHERE para que ele so retorne as consulta que estao agendadas para o dia que é comparado com a variavél dataFinal (var do programa Java que obtém a data no formato yyyy/MM/dd).

O Problema é que esta query só está retornando um único utente que tem um consulta nessa data , mas existem mais utentes que têm as mesmas datas associadas e não estão aparecendo.

Java:

```
public void componentShown(ComponentEvent arg0) {

            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
            Date date = new Date();
            System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));

            String dataFinal = dateFormat.format(date);

            try {

                Connection lig = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/htmdb", "root", "");
                PreparedStatement inst = lig

                        .prepareStatement(
                                "SELECT nome, sala_piso, nomeFuncionario, departamento, data, tempo, confirmacao FROM consulta "
                                        + "JOIN utentes ON consulta.utentes_utente_id = utentes.utente_id "
                                        + "JOIN funcionarios_has_consulta ON funcionarios_has_consulta.consulta_consulta_id = consulta.consulta_id "
                                        + "JOIN funcionarios ON funcionarios.funcionario_id = funcionarios_has_consulta.funcionarios_funcionario_id WHERE data ='"
                                        + dataFinal + "'  ");


                ResultSet rs = inst.executeQuery();

                tableAgendadas.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmHealthTreatmentManager, "Hoje é dia : " + dataFinal);

                lig.close();

            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmHealthTreatmentManager,
                        "Impossível ligar à base de dados. " + e1.getLocalizedMessage());

            }

        }
```

Base de Dados: 
[image: Base de dados]

Pretendo obter este resultado:

[image: retornocerto]

Comment: Editei a pergunta porque "phpmyadmin" não é um "banco de dados", leia isto pra entender as diferenças: [Qual a diferença entre o mysql e o phpmyadmin?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115692/3635)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, vamos lá. Aparentemente não há problema na sua query.

Diante do cenário exposto por você só posso imaginar que nem todas as tabelas tem os registros para fazer o JOIN, o que acabaria limitando o retorno da consulta.

Sendo assim, alterei a consulta para usar **LEFT JOIN**:

```
SELECT u.nome, 
       c.sala_piso,
       f.nomeFuncionario,
       f.departamento,
       c.data,
       c.tempo,
       c.confirmacao
  FROM consulta c
 INNER JOIN utentes u ON c.utentes_utente_id = u.utente_id 
  LEFT JOIN funcionarios_has_consulta fhc ON c.consulta_id = fhc.consulta_consulta_id
  LEFT JOIN funcionarios f ON fhc.funcionarios_funcionario_id f.funcionario_id
 WHERE c.data = '2016-06-17';
```

Algumas observações sobre a tabela **funcionario_has_consulta**:

- já que foi criada esta tabela de relação, quer dizer que você pode ter mais de uma profissional relacionado a uma consulta?
- tem necessidade de ter o campo do utente nesta tabela, já que ele está presente na consulta e a **chave primária da consulta** já está presente nesta tabela?

Comment: Refiz a base de dados e ajustei as queries , está tudo a funcionar como pretendido , muito obrigado ;) .