# Erro ao capturar os dados do Foreach e mandar para o PHPMailer

Tags: php, envio-de-email

Faço uma consulta no banco e estou imprimindo na tela normalmente através de um `foreach`. Estou com dificuldade para pegar os dados do `foreach` e mandar para o PHPMailer.

Meu código:

```
include "banco.php";    
function BuscaAlgo($conexao){    
      $query = "SELECT USU.experiencia,
                       USU.altura,
                       USU.peso,
                       PRAN.exp_ref,
                       PRAN.altura_ref,
                       PRAN.peso_ref,
                       PRAN.tipo_prancha,
                       PRAN.tamanho_prancha, 
                       PRAN.meio_prancha, 
                       PRAN.litragem_prancha       
                        FROM DADOS_USUARIO AS USU 
                             INNER JOIN PRANCHA AS PRAN
                                 on USU.experiencia = PRAN.exp_ref
                                  WHERE USU.altura = PRAN.altura_ref
                                    AND USU.peso = PRAN.peso_ref
                                      ORDER BY USU.usuario DESC LIMIT 1";

      //RETORNA A MENSAGEM COM O UTF8
      mysqli_set_charset($conexao, "utf8");

      //VARIÁVEL QUE GUARDA A CONSULTA NO BANCO
      $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao,$query);

        if( !$resultado ){
          die("Consulta falhou.");
        }

      $retorno = array();

      //PEGA TODOS OS VALORES DA CONSULTA E INSERE NO ARRAY $retorno[];
      while($experiencia = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
        $retorno[] = $experiencia;
      }

  return $resultado;
}

$resultado = array();
$resultado = BuscaAlgo($conexao);

//MEU FOREACH -> IMPRIME NA TELA 
foreach($resultado as $valor){
   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
   echo "<span class='desc'>TAMANHO 1:</span>"; echo $valor["tamanho_primeiro"]; print("<br>"); 
   echo "<span class='desc'>TAMANHO 2:</span>"; echo $valor["tamanho_segundo"]; print("<br>"); 
   echo "<span class='desc'>TAMANHO 3:</span>";  echo $valor["tamanho_terceiro"];  





include 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'meuemail@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'minhaSENHA';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->IsHTML(true);     
$mail->From = 'meuemail@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'REMETENTE';
$mail->addAddress('destinatario@hotmail.com');
$mail->Subject = 'E-mail PHPMailer';
$mail->Body;
 foreach($resultado as $valor){
  $mail->Body .=$valor["tamanho_primeiro"];
  $mail->Body .=$valor["tamanho_segundo"];
  $mail->Body .=$valor["tamanho_terceiro"];
 }

// Envia o e-mail e captura o sucesso ou erro
if($mail->Send()):
    echo 'Êxito no envio!';
else:
    echo 'Erro ao enviar Email:' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
endif;

 return $valor;
}
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

obs: O código do `PHPMailer` está funcionando corretamente. Testei-o em um outro arquivo, enviando um texto qualquer e o envio foi feito com sucesso.

**#ATUALIZAÇÃO**

//FOREACH

```
foreach($resultado as $valor){
   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
   echo "<span class='desc'>TAMANHO 1:</span>"; echo $valor["tamanho_primeiro"]; print("<br>"); 
   echo "<span class='desc'>TAMANHO 2:</span>"; echo $valor["tamanho_segundo"]; print("<br>"); 
   echo "<span class='desc'>TAMANHO 3:</span>";  echo $valor["tamanho_terceiro"];  

  $tamanho_pri = $valor["tamanho_primeiro"];
  $tamanho_seg = $valor["tamanho_segundo"];
  $tamanho_ter = $valor["tamanho_terceiro"];    
}
```

//PHPMAILER

```
$mail->Body = $tamanho_pri;
$mail->Body .= $tamanho_seg;
$mail->Body .= $tamanho_ter;
```

Fiz desta forma e está funcionando. Porém, esta é a melhor forma de fazer seguindo as boas práticas?

Comment: O que é essa dificuldade? poderia detalhar melhor

Comment: Ele não está enviando, este é o problema /:

Comment: Dei uma olhada no console do navegar=dor e não me aparece nenhum erro

Comment: vc tem dois foreach fazendo a mesma coisa ... e tem um `return $valor;` perdido

Comment: O primeiro `foreach` retorna para o usuário. O segundo `foreach` (na minha lógica), é para o PHPMailer

Comment: vc tem `foreach($resultado as $valor){` e depois `$mail->Body;
 foreach($resultado as $valor){`

Comment: Eu removi o `return $valor` e agora está enviando. Como eu posso ter um único `foreach` que seja enviado para o `PHPMailer` e imprimido na tela para o usuário?

Comment: É so remover o segundo, fazer a atribuição de `$mail->Body` e concatenar as strings.

Comment: Modifiquei o código e agora está funcionando. Do modo que fiz, está correto segundo as boas práticas? (atualizei o post)

Comment: É possível melhorar alguma coisas, por exemplo trocar aquelas 3 linhas do `$mail->body` por `$mail->Body = $valor["tamanho_primeiro"] . ' - '. $valor["tamanho_segundo"];` e tirar a configuração do phpmailer do foreach já que boa parte não vai mudar, deve ficar dentro do foreach o `send()` e `addAddress()` não esqueça de resetar os endereços de email do contrario o primeiro destinario vai receber todas as vezes o mesmo email.

Comment: Fiz as modificações, funcionou. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Editei a pergunta porque "phpmyadmin" não é um "banco de dados", leia isto pra entender as diferenças: [Qual a diferença entre o mysql e o phpmyadmin?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115692/3635)