# Unir dois select, como que faço?

Tags: mysql

Como unir estes dois SELECTS?

```
SELECT *
FROM doacao d
LEFT JOIN foto f ON (d.iddoacao = f.iddoacao)
WHERE (d.idbeneficiario IS NULL);

SELECT email
FROM doador dd
INNER JOIN doacao d ON (dd.iddoador = d.iddoador)
WHERE (dd.iddoador IS NOT NULL)
  AND (d.idbeneficiario IS NULL);
```

Comment: Obs preciso chamar os dois select pra jogar no sql, queria saber como faço isso, se uso o union?

Comment: vc quer exibir as duas consultas ou unir(union) elas?

Comment: Abrir duas abas não resolve o problema? ainda não deu p entender bem o que vc quer.

Comment: Unir elas no select

Comment: Padronize os campos dos dois selects e use `UNION ALL`

Comment: To tentando aqui so que nao ta funcionando.

Comment: Editei a pergunta porque "phpmyadmin" não é um "banco de dados", leia isto pra entender as diferenças: [Qual a diferença entre o mysql e o phpmyadmin?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115692/3635)

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer isso:

```
SELECT email, d.*
FROM doador dd
INNER JOIN doacao d ON (dd.iddoador = d.iddoador),
LEFT JOIN foto f ON (d.iddoacao = f.iddoacao)
WHERE (dd.iddoador IS NOT NULL)
      AND (d.idbeneficiario IS NULL);
```