# Configurar conexão do MySQL no eclipse

Tags: mysql, eclipse

Gostaria de saber se tem como fazer uma conexão com o MySQL pelo Eclipse.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Sim é possível conectar o eclipse diretamente ao MySQL, o primeiro passo é baixar o `.jar` do MySQL para a configuração.

Comment: Qual eclipse vc usa? JEE, PHP etc?

Comment: JEE. Poderiam postar um codigo de como fazer?

Comment: To montando uma resposta :)

Comment: Na verdade eu queria criar tabelas a partir do banco usando jpa, mas sempre da falha de conexao.

Comment: Editei a pergunta porque "phpmyadmin" não é um "banco de dados", leia isto pra entender as diferenças: [Qual a diferença entre o mysql e o phpmyadmin?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115692/3635)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O primeiro passo é baixar o [Jconnector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html) no site da Oracle

No eclipse JEE, mude a perspectiva database development, geralmente essa opção fica no canto superior direito.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Click com o botão direito em database connections, opção new.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na tela seguinte selecione o banco desejado(MySQL), na próxima informa os dados da conexão como servidor, usuário, senha e database.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que eu faço com o  Jconnector?

Comment: @RaphaelMelo não precisou dele? as vezes vc precisa para conectar pq a conexão é via jdbc.

Comment: Não consegui, o que devo por na URL.

Comment: @RaphaelMelo so altera o `database` para o nome da sua base. não esqueça do usuário senha(campos a baixo);

Comment: eu consegui conectar e visualizar todas as tabelas, porem, as tabelas vem sem os campos. O que pode ser?