# Como manipular Banco de Dados direto na IDE Eclipse?

Tags: java, postgresql, eclipse

É possível, talvez com algum plugin, manipular (gerenciar) bancos de dados PostgreeSQL com a IDE Eclipse?

Verifiquei o *DBViwer*, mas não tem opção para criação de tabela diretamente por dentro do Eclipse.

Comment: Seria algo como https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/138085/91 ?

Comment: seria possível fazer o CRUD através deste? no caso tornaria o eclipse em uma ide SGBD como por exemplo o pgAdmin ?

Comment: Isso, pelo eclipse vc consegue ver e manipular as base de dados, porém é limitado, se for para algo simples pode usar mas prefira o pgAdmin.

Comment: maravilha, então é isso mesmo, muito obrigado @rray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue link para pluguin do eclipse que permite utilizar dentro do eclipse a ferramenta de gerenciamento de banco de dados [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.com/eclipse/).