# Conexão MySQL Workbench no PHPmyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, amazon-aws, phpmyadmin

Bom dia.

Estou tentando fazer uma conexão remota do MySQL Workbench na minha nuvem da AWS, onde o PHPmyAdmin está instalado, porém não estou conseguindo.

O erro apresentado é:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já procurei no Google por este erro mas nada efetivo.

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: A porta 3306 está liberada na aws ?

Comment: tem certeza do nome do hostname?

Comment: @Douglas, sim, está.

Comment: @LuísAlmeida, fiquei com dúvida sobre isso, porém tentei o localhost(127.0.0.1) e o meu domínio, ambos apresentaram este mesmo erro (10061).

Comment: @João no painel da amazon você vai ver a url.

Comment: @João, esse `hostname` deve ser o mesmo do seu `endpoint` da configuração do seu **Amazon RDS** > **BD Instances**. copia e cola o que tem lá.

Comment: phpmyadmin não é um banco de dados, o banco é mysql e phpmyadmin é uma ferramenta, o mysql não precisa do phpmyadmin e o workbench não se comunica com o phpmyadmin, recomendo esta leitura: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115691/3635