# Aplicação Android dá erro quando tento fazer login

Tags: php, java, android, mysql

Aplicação de sistema log in no Android Studio.
Eu consigo registar-me na aplicação mas quando tento fazer o log in não consigo dame uma mensagem "login failed"
aqui está o código do login.php

```
<?php
require("password.php");

$con = mysqli_connect("198.91.81.5", "usuario", "senha", "mycloudb_bets");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $colUserID, $colName, $colUsername, $colAge, $colPassword);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    if (password_verify($password, $colPassword)) {
        $response["success"] = true;  
        $response["name"] = $colName;
        $response["age"] = $colAge;
    }
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Este ficheiro login.php chama o ficheiro password.php aqui está ele :

```
/**

 * A Compatibility library with PHP 5.5's simplified password hashing API.

*

* @author Anthony Ferrara <ircmaxell@php.net>

* @license http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.html MIT License

* @copyright 2012 The Authors

*/



namespace {



if (!defined('PASSWORD_BCRYPT')) {

    /**

     * PHPUnit Process isolation caches constants, but not function declarations.

     * So we need to check if the constants are defined separately from 

     * the functions to enable supporting process isolation in userland

     * code.

     */

    define('PASSWORD_BCRYPT', 1);

    define('PASSWORD_DEFAULT', PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    define('PASSWORD_BCRYPT_DEFAULT_COST', 10);

}



if (!function_exists('password_hash')) {



    /**

     * Hash the password using the specified algorithm

     *

     * @param string $password The password to hash

     * @param int    $algo     The algorithm to use (Defined by PASSWORD_* constants)

     * @param array  $options  The options for the algorithm to use

     *

     * @return string|false The hashed password, or false on error.

     */

    function password_hash($password, $algo, array $options = array()) {

        if (!function_exists('crypt')) {

            trigger_error("Crypt must be loaded for password_hash to function", E_USER_WARNING);

            return null;

        }

        if (is_null($password) || is_int($password)) {

            $password = (string) $password;

        }

        if (!is_string($password)) {

            trigger_error("password_hash(): Password must be a string", E_USER_WARNING);

            return null;

        }

        if (!is_int($algo)) {

            trigger_error("password_hash() expects parameter 2 to be long, " . gettype($algo) . " given", E_USER_WARNING);

            return null;

        }

        $resultLength = 0;

        switch ($algo) {

            case PASSWORD_BCRYPT:

                $cost = PASSWORD_BCRYPT_DEFAULT_COST;

                if (isset($options['cost'])) {

                    $cost = (int) $options['cost'];

                    if ($cost < 4 || $cost > 31) {

                        trigger_error(sprintf("password_hash(): Invalid bcrypt cost parameter specified: %d", $cost), E_USER_WARNING);

                        return null;

                    }

                }

                // The length of salt to generate

                $raw_salt_len = 16;

                // The length required in the final serialization

                $required_salt_len = 22;

                $hash_format = sprintf("$2y$%02d$", $cost);

                // The expected length of the final crypt() output

                $resultLength = 60;

                break;

            default:

                trigger_error(sprintf("password_hash(): Unknown password hashing algorithm: %s", $algo), E_USER_WARNING);

                return null;

        }

        $salt_req_encoding = false;

        if (isset($options['salt'])) {

            switch (gettype($options['salt'])) {

                case 'NULL':

                case 'boolean':

                case 'integer':

                case 'double':

                case 'string':

                    $salt = (string) $options['salt'];

                    break;

                case 'object':

                    if (method_exists($options['salt'], '__tostring')) {

                        $salt = (string) $options['salt'];

                        break;

                    }

                case 'array':

                case 'resource':

                default:

                    trigger_error('password_hash(): Non-string salt parameter supplied', E_USER_WARNING);

                    return null;

            }

            if (PasswordCompat\binary\_strlen($salt) < $required_salt_len) {

                trigger_error(sprintf("password_hash(): Provided salt is too short: %d expecting %d", PasswordCompat\binary\_strlen($salt), $required_salt_len), E_USER_WARNING);

                return null;

            } elseif (0 == preg_match('#^[a-zA-Z0-9./]+$#D', $salt)) {

                $salt_req_encoding = true;

            }

        } else {

            $buffer = '';

            $buffer_valid = false;

            if (function_exists('mcrypt_create_iv') && !defined('PHALANGER')) {

                $buffer = mcrypt_create_iv($raw_salt_len, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);

                if ($buffer) {

                    $buffer_valid = true;

                }

            }

            if (!$buffer_valid && function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes')) {

                $strong = false;

                $buffer = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($raw_salt_len, $strong);

                if ($buffer && $strong) {

                    $buffer_valid = true;

                }

            }

            if (!$buffer_valid && @is_readable('/dev/urandom')) {

                $file = fopen('/dev/urandom', 'r');

                $read = 0;

                $local_buffer = '';

                while ($read < $raw_salt_len) {

                    $local_buffer .= fread($file, $raw_salt_len - $read);

                    $read = PasswordCompat\binary\_strlen($local_buffer);

                }

                fclose($file);

                if ($read >= $raw_salt_len) {

                    $buffer_valid = true;

                }

                $buffer = str_pad($buffer, $raw_salt_len, "\0") ^ str_pad($local_buffer, $raw_salt_len, "\0");

            }

            if (!$buffer_valid || PasswordCompat\binary\_strlen($buffer) < $raw_salt_len) {

                $buffer_length = PasswordCompat\binary\_strlen($buffer);

                for ($i = 0; $i < $raw_salt_len; $i++) {

                    if ($i < $buffer_length) {

                        $buffer[$i] = $buffer[$i] ^ chr(mt_rand(0, 255));

                    } else {

                        $buffer .= chr(mt_rand(0, 255));

                    }

                }

            }

            $salt = $buffer;

            $salt_req_encoding = true;

        }

        if ($salt_req_encoding) {

            // encode string with the Base64 variant used by crypt

            $base64_digits =

                'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';

            $bcrypt64_digits =

                './ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';



            $base64_string = base64_encode($salt);

            $salt = strtr(rtrim($base64_string, '='), $base64_digits, $bcrypt64_digits);

        }

        $salt = PasswordCompat\binary\_substr($salt, 0, $required_salt_len);



        $hash = $hash_format . $salt;



        $ret = crypt($password, $hash);



        if (!is_string($ret) || PasswordCompat\binary\_strlen($ret) != $resultLength) {

            return false;

        }



        return $ret;

    }



    /**

     * Get information about the password hash. Returns an array of the information

     * that was used to generate the password hash.

     *

     * array(

     *    'algo' => 1,

     *    'algoName' => 'bcrypt',

     *    'options' => array(

     *        'cost' => PASSWORD_BCRYPT_DEFAULT_COST,

     *    ),

     * )

     *

     * @param string $hash The password hash to extract info from

     *

     * @return array The array of information about the hash.

     */

    function password_get_info($hash) {

        $return = array(

            'algo' => 0,

            'algoName' => 'unknown',

            'options' => array(),

        );

        if (PasswordCompat\binary\_substr($hash, 0, 4) == '$2y$' && PasswordCompat\binary\_strlen($hash) == 60) {

            $return['algo'] = PASSWORD_BCRYPT;

            $return['algoName'] = 'bcrypt';

            list($cost) = sscanf($hash, "$2y$%d$");

            $return['options']['cost'] = $cost;

        }

        return $return;

    }



    /**

     * Determine if the password hash needs to be rehashed according to the options provided

     *

     * If the answer is true, after validating the password using password_verify, rehash it.

     *

     * @param string $hash    The hash to test

     * @param int    $algo    The algorithm used for new password hashes

     * @param array  $options The options array passed to password_hash

     *

     * @return boolean True if the password needs to be rehashed.

     */

    function password_needs_rehash($hash, $algo, array $options = array()) {

        $info = password_get_info($hash);

        if ($info['algo'] !== (int) $algo) {

            return true;

        }

        switch ($algo) {

            case PASSWORD_BCRYPT:

                $cost = isset($options['cost']) ? (int) $options['cost'] : PASSWORD_BCRYPT_DEFAULT_COST;

                if ($cost !== $info['options']['cost']) {

                    return true;

                }

                break;

        }

        return false;

    }



    /**

     * Verify a password against a hash using a timing attack resistant approach

     *

     * @param string $password The password to verify

     * @param string $hash     The hash to verify against

     *

     * @return boolean If the password matches the hash

     */

    function password_verify($password, $hash) {

        if (!function_exists('crypt')) {

            trigger_error("Crypt must be loaded for password_verify to function", E_USER_WARNING);

            return false;

        }

        $ret = crypt($password, $hash);

        if (!is_string($ret) || PasswordCompat\binary\_strlen($ret) != PasswordCompat\binary\_strlen($hash) || PasswordCompat\binary\_strlen($ret) <= 13) {

            return false;

        }



        $status = 0;

        for ($i = 0; $i < PasswordCompat\binary\_strlen($ret); $i++) {

            $status |= (ord($ret[$i]) ^ ord($hash[$i]));

        }



        return $status === 0;

    }

}



}



namespace PasswordCompat\binary {



if (!function_exists('PasswordCompat\\binary\\_strlen')) {



    /**

     * Count the number of bytes in a string

     *

     * We cannot simply use strlen() for this, because it might be overwritten by the mbstring extension.

     * In this case, strlen() will count the number of *characters* based on the internal encoding. A

     * sequence of bytes might be regarded as a single multibyte character.

     *

     * @param string $binary_string The input string

     *

     * @internal

     * @return int The number of bytes

     */

    function _strlen($binary_string) {

        if (function_exists('mb_strlen')) {

            return mb_strlen($binary_string, '8bit');

        }

        return strlen($binary_string);

    }



    /**

     * Get a substring based on byte limits

     *

     * @see _strlen()

     *

     * @param string $binary_string The input string

     * @param int    $start

     * @param int    $length

     *

     * @internal

     * @return string The substring

     */

    function _substr($binary_string, $start, $length) {

        if (function_exists('mb_substr')) {

            return mb_substr($binary_string, $start, $length, '8bit');

        }

        return substr($binary_string, $start, $length);

    }



    /**

     * Check if current PHP version is compatible with the library

     *

     * @return boolean the check result

     */

    function check() {

        static $pass = NULL;



        if (is_null($pass)) {

            if (function_exists('crypt')) {

                $hash = '$2y$04$usesomesillystringfore7hnbRJHxXVLeakoG8K30oukPsA.ztMG';

                $test = crypt("password", $hash);

                $pass = $test == $hash;

            } else {

                $pass = false;

            }

        }

        return $pass;

    }



}

}
```

Aqui está o código java que chama o ficheiro.php

```
public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {
private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://mycloudbets.pcriot.com/Login2.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public LoginRequest(String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
    super(Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("password", password);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
}
```

Aqui está o código java onde tem o código a dizer para aparecer a mensagem de erro:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    final TextView tvRegisterLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegisterLink);
    final Button bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSignIn);

    tvRegisterLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
        }
    });

    bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

            // Response received from the server
            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if (success) {
                            String name = jsonResponse.getString("name");
                            int age = jsonResponse.getInt("age");

                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("name", name);
                            intent.putExtra("age", age);
                            intent.putExtra("username", username);
                            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Login Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(username, password, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
            queue.add(loginRequest);
        }
    });
}
}
```

A variavel `response` em `onResponse(String response)` retorna isto:

```
{"success":false}
```

Comment: Can you translate your question, for not close?

Comment: Sim já estou a por em português pensei que estava na versão do stackoverflow em ingles

Comment: Por favor não coloque código em imagens, é difícil para quem for querer ajudá-lo...

Comment: Eu não consegui pôr o código normal ficava desformatado dei voltas e voltas só consegui mesmo pôr esse do php em código o resto teve que ser em imagens

Comment: Faça como fez com o anterior... eu tento arrumar o restante...e coloque o erro caso houver...

Comment: Ok consegui pôr direito como você pediu

Comment: Só uma dica, phpmyadmin não tem nada haver com mysql, talvez isto lhe ajude a entender http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115691/3635

Comment: Sobre o problema faça isto para testar o resultado `public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try { Log.d("RESPOSTA_HTTP", response);` e informa aqui qual foi o resultado, se não encontrar procure no console pela palavra `RESPOSTA_HTTP`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento onde coloco esse código para testar ?

Comment: `public void onResponse(String response) ` é seu proprio código, eu só adicionei o `Log.d("RESPOSTA_HTTP", response);`, procura por `onReponse` no teu código e modifica para ficar igual ao trecho que eu mostrei de exemplo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o logcat deu isso
12-03 16:45:43.118 20029-20029/com.tonikamitv.loginregister D/RESPOSTA_HTTP: {"success":false}
12-03 16:45:43.202 20029-20059/com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-03 16:45:43.203 20029-20059/com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabebf960, error=EGL_SUCCESS

Comment: Vou tentar verificar, o problema pelo jeito é na função `password_verify`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento está bem obrigado por me estar ajudar