# Deletar Registro no Bd

Tags: php, mysqli

Criei uma sistema para criação de post. 
Mas não estou conseguindo deletar no banco mas aparece a confirmação de Excluido com Sucesso!

```
<?php
       $db = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "photos");
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM images";
       $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo "<div class='post-item'> <div class='inner'>";
          echo "  <div class='post-title'><h2><a href='#'> ".$row['titulo']."</a></h2></div>";
          echo "<div class='post-image'><div></div><img src='images/".$row['image']."'></div ";
          echo " <div class='post-meta-top'>Posted <span class='post-date'>2 days ago</span> </div>
                                <div class='clear'></div> ";
          echo "    <div class='post-desc'>
                                    <p>".$row['texto']."</p>
                                </div>";
           echo "                     <a href='?id=".$row['id']."&Acao=Deletar'><button>Deletar</button></a> 
                            </div>
                        </div>";                      
}


if (isset($_GET['Acao']) && $_GET['Acao'] == 'Deletar') {
   $id = $_GET['id'];
   $sql = mysqli_query("DELETE FROM images WHERE id='$id' ");

   if ($result) { 
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Comentario Excluido!"); </script>';
   } else { 
       echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Erro!"); </script>';
   }

}
?>
```

Comment: Só use a tag [tag:phpmyadmin] se o problema for com o phpmyadmin mesmo, no seu caso o problema é com o script e/ou mysql. Phpmyadmin não é uma aplicação a parte e não influencia no teu script, recomendo esta leitura: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115691/3635

Answer (score 8):

- Você está testando `$result`, sendo que guardou o objeto de resultado na *query* na variável `$sql`

  ```
  $sql = mysqli_query("DELETE FROM images WHERE id='$id' ");
  ^^^^
  if ($result) { 
      ^^^^^^^
  ```
- A nomenclatura está ruim, pois SQL é o que está entre aspas, e não o retorno do `mysqli_query`, que como mencionado é um objeto.
- Você está fazendo *queries* sem por o link da conexão, convém sempre ler o o Manual, para não precisar fazer uma pergunta a cada linha de código.

  Notar que isto é uma dica para facilitar sua vida, pois lendo o manual o seu trabalho vai render muito mais. Nada contra você perguntar, estamos aqui pra ajudar, mas tudo que for mais simples e conseguir resolver por conta própria, vai agilizar seu tempo.
- Para saber quantos registros foram afetados (sejam inseridos, atualizados ou removidos) a função mais adequada é `mysqli_affected_rows($link)`.

  Muitas vezes a *query* pode ter sido bem sucedida, mas não ser encontrado nenhum registro que satisfaça o `WHERE`, aí seu teste vai falhar.
- Importante, se puser esse código no ar, seu DB vai ser destruído a todo momento, pois você não sanitizou seus dados e qualquer um faz injeção no código.

Tem outras considerações, mas se resolver esses ítens acima já é um bom começo. A sugestão é de fazer pequenos testes separados até dominar o básico, e uma vez funcionando, colocar no código principal.

Sobre o trecho do `if`, uma melhoria seria essa:

```
// forçando que $id seja um número:
// (o ideal seria fazer um teste mais complexo, já que esse cast não
// evita que quebrem o código mandando um array.
// De qq forma, isto já evita a injeção, que é o maior perigo)
$id = 0 + $id; 

// guardando o objeto de resultado em $result        
$result = mysqli_query($link, 'DELETE FROM images WHERE id='.$id);

// e testando  1) se a query foi executada  2) se deletou algo de fato
if(!$result) {
    ... houve um problema na query ...
} elseif( mysqli_affected_rows($link) > 0 ) {
    ... deletou um ou mais registros ...
} else {
    ... a query foi realizada, mas nao foi deletado nenhum registro ...
}
```

Recomendaria uma boa leitura nos links a seguir:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php

> [Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/70)