# O que mysql.sys?

Tags: php, mysql

Boa Noite Pessoal,

Acabei de instalar o wampserver,posteriormente fui acesso o phpmyadmin,porém achei algo estranho nas contas de usuários.

Como usuários tinha somente o mysql.sys e o root, sendo o "root" o  qual eu criei.

Alguém pode me falar ago sobre isso?
E algo decorrente da versão do phpmyadmin?

Comment: Se não me engano ele é o usuário da tabela `test`, isso é desde de o MySQL 5.7.

Comment: **Relacionado:** [Qual a diferença entre o MySQL e o phpMyAdmin?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115691/3635)

Answer (score 7):

Desde o MySQL 5.7.7 é criado um *Schema* para facilitar as estatísticas de performance gerenciadas pelo *engine* `PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA`, e ele é justamente o `sys`.

Também foi criado este usuário (chamado de `DEFINER` neste contexto):

```
'mysql.sys'@'localhost'
```

Isto foi feito para evitar problemas, pois antes o `DEFINER` era o

```
'root'@'localhost'
```

e isto criava uma série de problemas quando o usuário `root` era renomeado, o que é um procedimento de segurança muito comum.

A criação de um usuário dedicado e somente local foi a solução encontrada.

Mais detalhes no manual:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-schema.html

Comment: obrigado.Valeuuu.

Comment: @MarcosTulio se resolveu, você pode marcar com o V verdinho do lado da pontuação, para marcar como resposta escolhida