# Como gerar automático os campos

Tags: php, html, mysql

Preciso ir no banco de dados buscar a img e ir exibindo ela em cada `<li> </li>` do carousel, porém precisava deixar isso automático, pois são muitaas fotos, tem alguma maneira?

```
<div id="wrapper">      
    <div id="carousel" class="carousel">
      <div class="call-to-content wow fadeInUp">
        <h3>fileira 1</h3>
      </div>
        <a class="nav prev" href="#"></a>

        <div class="carousel_items_holder">
            <ul class="carousel_items">
                <li>
                 <a href="#">
                  <?php
                      $img=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM arquivo WHERE id_pessoa = 1 ORDER BY visu DESC limit 0,1 ") 
                      or die("Impossível executar a query");        

                      $nome=mysql_query("SELECT  nome, id_pessoa FROM arquivo WHERE id_pessoa = 1   
                      ORDER BY visu DESC limit 0,1") or die("Impossível executar a query");

                      while($row=mysql_fetch_object($img)) { 
                          echo "<img src='getImagem.php?PicNum=$row->codigo' \">"; 
                      } 

                      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($nome)) { 
                          $c_nome = $row["nome"];
                          $c_id = $row["id_pessoa"];
                      }         

                   ?>
                </a> 

                <div class="center">
                    <p>
                      <?php             
                        echo "<a href='perfil.php?id=$c_id'> $c_nome </a>";             
                     ?>
                    </p>
                </div>  
                </li>   
        <a class="nav next" href="#"></a>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Arquivo conexao

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "imagem";

$link = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("Impossível conectar ao banco."); 

@mysqli_select_db($db) or die("Impossível conectar ao banco");
```

?>

Com esse código acima, eu insiro manualmente, porém precisava automático, possui alguma maneira?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há muitos problemas:

1. Primeiro Phpmyadmin não é tem nada haver com o problema (só estou comentando porque você colocou a tag phpmyadmin na pergunta, veja o [**review**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/181520/revisions)), leia:

   - [Qual a diferença entre o MySQL e o phpMyAdmin?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115691/3635)
2. Segundo teu HTML está cheio de problemas, está me parecendo só um problema de erro de digitação
3. Terceiro **não use** mais as funções que comecem com `mysql_`, use `mysqli_` ou `PDO`, leia:

   - [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/3635)
4. Não é necessário duas queries para uma única tabela neste caso especifico

---

O código de conexão deve ficar assim:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "imagem";

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf('Connect failed: %s\n', mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

E o teu HTML ficaria melhor assim:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='carousel' class='carousel'>
      <div class='call-to-content wow fadeInUp'>
        <h3>fileira 1</h3>
      </div>
        <a class='nav prev' href='#'></a>

        <div class='carousel_items_holder'>
        <?php
        $resultado = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT nome, id_pessoa, codigo FROM arquivo ORDER BY visu DESC');
        ?>

        <?php if (!$resultado): ?>
            <p>Impossivel conectar</p>

            <?php else: ?>
                <ul class='carousel_items'>
                <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC)): ?>

                <li>
                    <a href='perfil.php?id=<?php echo $row['id_pessoa']; ?>'>
                        <img src='getImagem.php?PicNum=<?php echo $row['codigo']; ?>'>
                    </a>

                    <div class='center'>
                        <p><?php echo $row['nome']; ?></p>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <a class='nav next' href='#'></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: esta dando erro no meu arquivo de conexão, de uma olhada pf, vou deixar na pergunta ele

Comment: nao deu certo, ele nao exibe nada, mas se eu mudar pra mysql e com meu codigo de conexao, ele funciona, tem algo errado nessa parte do mysqli

Comment: tava faltando no mysql_fetch_array, vc n colocou mysqli, deu certo, obrigado

Comment: ss, eu entendi é q no seu codigo vc colocou mysql, ai eu arrumei pra mysqli

Comment: @GuilhermeFelipeSimão nossa vacilei, desculpa :)

Comment: haha tudo bem, estou tendo um problema em outro carousel meu, preciso limitar ele pra exibir apenas 4 img dos maiores valores. 

<?php
        $resultado = mysqli_query($link,'SELECT  codigo FROM arquivo ORDER BY visu DESC limit 0,4');
?>

Usei o limit, mas n deu certo, ele nao exibe corretamente dentro do carousel

Comment: @GuilhermeFelipeSimão não tá faltando 2 colunas? Tenta assim `$resultado = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT nome, id_pessoa, codigo FROM arquivo ORDER BY visu DESC LIMIT 4');`

Comment: é outro código q estou tendo problemas, o seu deu certo. Tentei LIMIT 4, ele exibiu 4 so q um embaixo do outro e não dentro do carousel lado a lodo.

Comment: @GuilhermeFelipeSimão vc deve ter mexido no HTML, ou o teu carousel não está funcionando.

Comment: Eu crio outra pergunta com o novo código, ou posso editar essa pergunta aqui ?

Comment: Não precisa, faz o seguinte abre a página pelo firefox ou chrome, aperta Ctrl+U, vai aparecer o código-fonte gerado em HTML apenas, copia tudo e cola no http://pastebin.com e manda pra mim.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8DYQ6SMG   aqui

Comment: @GuilhermeFelipeSimão o que eu disse? Eu disse "abra a página pelo firefox chrome e pegue o HTML gerado", vc me mandou o PHP. O PHP não adianta preciso do resultado depois de vocÊ acessar pelo navegador. Outra coisa, vc colocou link dentro de link e já mudou todo o HTML, já não tem nada haver com o da resposta aqui, assim não tem como resolver, faz o seguinte só me manda o código fonte gerado.

Comment: @GuilhermeFelipeSimão olhando aqui, vc novamente estragou (com o perdão da palavra) o HTML, tem tag sem fechar e link dentro de link, e o que deveria estar dentro do WHILE vc colocou fora. Tá cheio de problema de novo.

Comment: eita, estou aprendendo ainda =/. Desculpa, agra é o link com html gerado. http://pastebin.com/fTtsbtn2

Answer (score 0):

Nem quero entrar em detalhes de estar fazendo `SELECT` na view, mas vamos la.
Esta fazendo o loop (while) dentro do `<li>` no caso, deveria ser fora dele né, tipo assim:

```
<ul class="carousel_items">
    <?php
        $img=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM arquivo WHERE id_pessoa = 1 ORDER BY visu DESC limit 0,1 ") 
        or die("Impossível executar a query");
    ?>

    <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($img)) { ?>

        <li>
          <a href="#">
              <?php  echo "<img src='getImagem.php?PicNum=$row->codigo' \">"; ?>
          </a> 

      </li> 

    <?php } ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: Pq não pode fazer dentro do <li>?

Comment: se fizer dentro do LI vc estara somente gerando loop das imagens e não de uma lista que é o que parece que vc precisa pelo que entendi da sua questão

Comment: Esse código que mostrei, ele busca uma img e coloca na LI, ai na outra LI teria q copiar código dnv e colocar na LI e assim por diante, queria saber se tem como ele fazer uma busca só no banco e ir criando automático as LI com os dados.

Comment: então, da forma q coloquei ele vai buscar no banco e vai criando automaticamente as LI