# Como conectar ao Mysql do Xampp de outro servidor com o linux instalado?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Olá eu tenho um servidor de testes conhecido como Xampp nele eu tenho um banco de dados ativo no mysql, só que eu tenho também um outro servidor com o apache rodando em outra maquina, e é nesta maquina que eu quero rodar os códigos em php, na maquina local assim funciona:

```
$icon = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$icon) {
    die('<br/>Não foi possível conectar: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    echo 'Conexão bem sucedida';
}
```

porem ao tentar do outro servidor

```
$icon = mysql_connect("192.168.157.59:3306","root","");
if (!$icon) {
    die('<br/>Não foi possível conectar: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    echo 'Conexão bem sucedida';
}
```

Não da certo.
estes testes não deram certo. 
192.168.157.59:3306, http://192.168.157.59:3306, 192.168.157.59
nenhuma destas maneiras consegui fazer a conexão, o que impede?

Comment: O servidor tem que estar com as portas abertas, no IPTables, por exemplo, e em qualquer outro firewall. Além disso o usuário tem que está autorizado a se conectar neste host/ip.

Answer (score 1):

**PhpMyAdmin não tem ligação alguma com acessar o MySql através das APIs:**

- `mysql_`
- `mysqli`
- `PDO`

Como eu já expliquei em:

- [Qual a diferença entre o MySQL e o phpMyAdmin?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115691/3635)

O mysql é um servidor que funciona por TCP, mas não por HTTP, em instalações como Xampp e Wamp ele não esta ligado diretamente ao Apache ou PHP, ele na verdade é um servidor de banco de dados totalmente separado que pode ser instalado até em um computador diferente de uma mesma rede ou de uma rede externa que seja acessível e fica em uma porta diferente do HTTP.

Ele não tem navegação de pastas igual aos servidores HTTP ele fica em uma porta diferente, enquanto Apache, Ngnix, Lighttpd ficam geralmente em portas como 80, 8000, 8080, 9000, já o Mysql na maioria das vezes fica na porta 3306.

---

O que foi feito em nas configurações do Apache foi liberar o PHPMYADMIN:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Require all granted
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

Isso quer dizer que você esta acessando o phpmyadmin através de outro computador, mas não quer dizer que esteja acessando o a conexão TCP com o **servidor mysql**, pois isso não tem relação alguma com Apache.

---

### Como liberar para acessar o protocolo mysql de uma máquina diferente

Supondo que seja a mesma rede e seja Windows, então o que você deve fazer é liberar a porta no Firewall da máquina aonde se localiza o MySql-sever, então vá em Firewall do Window > <kbd>Regras de entrada</kbd> > <kbd>Nova Regra...</kbd> (canto direito superior) > <kbd>Porta</kbd>, como na imagem:

> [image: porta no firewall]

Então selecione TCP e digite a porta:

> [image: porta TCP no firewall]

Selecione a opção <kbd>Permitir conexão</kbd>, agora na próxima tela você pode optar aonde isto vai se aplicar, geralmente removemos redes publicas, pois creio eu que se o seu computador estiver no escritório ou na sua casa você use o <kbd>Perfil Particular</kbd>, logo provavelmente deva remover a opção publico que é descrita na imagem:

> [image: regra firewall se aplica]

Ele vai pedir um nome para a regra, é mais para você se guiar e remover ou desabilitar a regra quando desejar, digite "MYSQL", a descrição pode deixar em branco, deve ficar assim:

> [image: mysql liberado no firewall]

Pronto, desta forma qualquer máquina na rede vai poder acessar a máquina que esta o mysql-server, então para testar vá em uma máquina diferente da máquina aonde esta o MySql-server, você pode usar o comando de linha `telnet` (nem todo sistema Windows tem este programa ou permite instalar, geralmente o "Windows Pro" já tem), um teste simples no CMD seria digitar isto:

```
telnet 192.168.157.59 3306
```

A porta e o IP devem ser separados por espaços, como na imagem:

> [image: telnet para testar conexão com mysql]

Então aperte o Enter, se der qualquer mensagem de erro é porque algo esta errado nas suas configurações, para isso verifique:

1. Nas regras do firewall da máquina que configurou a porta se existe alguma outra regra de mysql que no caso deve estar bloqueando o acesso
2. Verifique se o mysql-server esta iniciado

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver o problema na versão do Xampp v3.2.2 deve ir na pasta C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra localizar e editar o arquivo. httpd-xampp.conf
localizar o texto onde esta esta estrutura

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

remova o texto Require local e substitua por Require all granted
veja logo abaixo como deve ficar

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Require all granted
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

Fazendo isto para o serviço do Apache e do MySql e reinicie os serviços.

Pronto agora poder acessar pela sua intranet.

Comment: Existe outro detalhe para que o código php demonstrado aqui execute, acesse o phpMyAdmin localize a base de dados mysql depois a tabela user, entre esta tabela e localize o user root onde o host é 127.0.0.1 e substitua por %.%.%.% salve, desta maneira ira conseguir fazer a conexão remota com o bando, não esqueça de reinicializar os serviços.