# ERRO: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php

Quando uso o meu formulário para fazer a busca em conexão php, aparece esse erro:

> Access denied for user 'clientes_assoc'@'localhost' (using password:
>   YES)

A minha conexão está assim:

```
<?php
 $hostdb = "localhost";
 $userdb = "clientes_assoc"; 
 $passdb = "senha";
 $tabledb = "assocs";

$conecta = mysql_connect($hostdb, $userdb, $passdb) or die (mysql_error());
@mysql_select_db($tabledb, $conecta) or die ("Erro ao conectar com o banco de dados");

?>
```

Não sei como resolver, já que o usuário está com todas as permissões.

Comment: Já testou essas credenciais criando uma conexão em um cliente de MySQL?

Comment: Já sim! E ainda sim não consigo resolver

Comment: Troca localhost por 127.0.0.1

Comment: Esta no seu computador ou esta em um site?

Comment: Está em um site. e troquei por 127.0.0.1 e continua mostrando a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hospedagens, servidores, etc, geralmente não tem o servidor MySQL na mesma máquina que o Apache (aonde fica o php e etc), isto porque geralmente as estações aonde ficam os servidores de bancos de dados são separadas, então você deve acessar o painel de sua Hospedagem/VPS ou seja o que for e verificar qual o HOST ou IP esta o teu servidor mysql.

> Recomendo que leia isto: [Qual a diferença entre o MySQL e o phpMyAdmin?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115691/3635)

Note que geralmente hospedagens até mesmo mais baratas podem ter múltiplos servidores mySql, por isto também não teria muito sentido usar `localhost` como host.

Geralmente o servidor usa um subdominio com seu host, por exemplo:

- Site http: `www.site.com`
- Servidor mysql: `msql.site.com`

Isto é apenas um exemplo ilustrativo, no geral seria **algo como**:

```
<?php
$hostdb = "mysql.meuservidor123.com";
$userdb = "clientes_assoc"; 
$passdb = "senha";
$tabledb = "assocs";

$conecta = mysql_connect($hostdb, $userdb, $passdb) or die (mysql_error());
```

Recomendo também não usar a API de prefixo `mysql_` ela é obsoleta, hoje temos as APIs `mysqli` e `PDO`, leia sobre em:

- [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/3635)