# PHP somente se conecta com o MySQL?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Nunca vi PHP se conectar usando outros bancos de dados, como o Oracle, por exemplo. No MySQL, pra conectar, usa-se `mysqli connect`, e se fosse em outro? O PHP é integrável com quais banco de dados?

Comment: Tem uma serie de bancos, postgresql, sql server, oracle, driver genérico odbc etc

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quase todos bancos usam protocolos próprios que rodam "sob o [*TCP*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)" geralmente, mesmo que o PHP não tenha uma *API nativa* para um tipo de banco especifico é possível escrever algo próprio, claro que é bem trabalhoso já que terá que entender o protocolo do banco especifico.

Além do mysql existem outros bancos suportados **nativamente** pelo PHP, segue a lista de bancos suportados (geralmente é necessário ativar uma extensão):

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/refs.database.php

Fora isto o PHP também usa `PDO` que é uma API "padronizada" para diferentes bancos: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php

> **Nota:** Não vou enumerar todos bancos, porque isso é uma coisa que pode mudar, então deixo o link da documentação oficial, para que fique mais fácil acompanhar o que foi descontinuado e novos suportes.

Vale ressaltar que o [mysql **não roda junto** com o PHP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html), não precisam nem estar no mesmo servidor, mysql assim como outros bancos geralmente estão em locais diferentes (depende do tipo de banco de dados), é importante entender isto para entender a questão de uma linguagem suportar algo, ou seja existe **suporte nativo** e existe a possibilidade de escrever algo próprio ou usar um *3rdparty*.

Eu mesmo certa vez escrevi uma classe para envio de SMTP própria e usei uma classe *3rdparty* para FTP ao invés de usar as funções nativas (existia um bug no servidor que eu usava, na versão do PHP que era um pouco antiga).

Todos exemplos que citei são como a maioria dos bancos de dados, usam uma comunicação por [*TCP*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) (geralmente/sempre/?), então quero dizer mesmo que a linguagem não suporte algo nativamente ainda sim pode ser possível que existe uma extensão criado por terceiros (`.dll` no windows e `.so` em unix-like) ou até mesmo um script escrito em PHP que provê funcionalidades para se comunicar com um tipo de banco não suportado nativamente.

Relacionado:

- [Qual a diferença entre o MySQL e o phpMyAdmin?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115691/3635)

Esta explicação sobre a comunicação *"linguagem vs banco"* é algo que pode ser "aplicado" para algumas outras linguagens/tecnologias, um exemplo de outra tecnologia é o [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/), aonde ele não veem com suporte nativo a bancos, mas você pode instalar via [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com), por exemplo instalar o mysql:

```
npm install mysql
```

Comment: Mas o phpmyadmin não é so uma plataforma que usa MySQL? Ou o PhpMyAdmin também é um banco de dados?

Comment: @LucasCarvalho A questão não é bem esta, eu linkei a pergunta para que você consiga entender aonde esta o PHP e aonde esta o MySql, o PhpMyadmin não é um banco, eu deixei isso bem explicito na resposta da pergunta que linkei, o *"foco é"*: *Vale ressaltar que o mysql não roda junto com o PHP, não precisam nem estar no mesmo servidor*, que é o ponto importante para entender porque a questão de suporte para um banco no PHP pode ser algo **extremamente** relativo ;)

Comment: @LucasCarvalho editei a resposta, só queria ressaltar o que são as APIs nativas e a questão da linguagem e suporte, espero que esteja um pouco mais fácil de entender.

Answer (score 12):

Usando a biblioteca do PDO, é possível se conectar com 12 tipos de bancos de dados.

> Lista:

1. [CUBRID](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-cubrid.php)
2. [MS SQL Server](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php)
3. [Firebird](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-firebird.php)
4. [IBM](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-ibm.php)
5. [Informix](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-informix.php)
6. [MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)
7. [MS SQL Server](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php)
8. [Oracle](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php)
9. [ODBC and DB2](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php)
10. [PostgreSQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.php)
11. [SQLite](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php)
12. [4D](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-4d.php)

Para mais informações sobre o uso dessas conexões você pode estar fazendo a consulta na documentação oficial do PDO no PHP em http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php

O PDO é só uma das extensões para se acessar base de dados no Php, caso deseje conhecer outras extensões pode consultar em http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/refs.database.php.

Answer (score 10):

Em tese ele pode ser integrado com qualquer banco de dados. Em geral a conexão é feita através de uma extensão para o banco de dados. E quando nada disso funcionar provavelmente poderá usar [ODBC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php), que não é tão bom quanto o acesso nativo.

Algumas extensões já costumam vir junto com o PHP. É verdade que o [MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mysqlinfo.php) é o mais usado, mas é comum usar [SQLite](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php), já que ele é mais simples, costuma ter melhor performance, é muito adequado para web, e tão poderoso quanto o MySQL, além de ser até mis confiável em certos cenários. Outros são:

- [PostgreSQL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pgsql.php)
- [Firebird](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ibase.php)
- [Oracle](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php)
- [SQL Server](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php), o que provavelmente aumentará o uso no Linux
- [DB2](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ibm-db2.php)
- [Informix](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ifx.php)
- [CUBRID](http://php.net/manual/en/book.cubrid.php)
- [MongoDB](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php)
- [dBase](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dbase.php) (DBF, Clipper/Harbour/FoxPro)

Entre outros menos conhecidos. Uma [lista completa atual pode ser vista na documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.database.php).

Sempre que for usar uma tecnologia deve ser toda sua documentação. As pessoas usam só um banco de dados por ele ter se tornado popular, e ele se tornou popular porque as pessoas só usam o que é popular.

è possível usar alguma abstração para acessar diversos banco de dados sem precisar saber dos detalhes, em geral isto tem várias desvantagens e a vantagem que elas oferecem normalmente não é necessária pela aplicação. Claro que a abstração só pode acessar bancos que ela entende e que op PHP sabe manipular, mesmo que através de uma extensão de terceiros.

Se não tiver motivos fortes e reais (não fantasias que as pessoas adotam), não use PDO.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

Ao falarmos sobre **[extensões de banco de dados](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/refs.database.php)** voltado ao PHP, segundo a documentação, existem dois grupos distintos:

1. As camadas de abstrações, e;
2. Extensões de banco de dados específicas do fornecedor.

Referente as camadas de abstrações a documentação cita quatro tipos de camadas, ou seja, são quatro representações de conexão entre PHP e um servidor de banco de dados, são elas:

1. DBA - Database (dbm-style) Abstraction Layer

   > DBA: São funções que criam as bases para acessar os bancos de dados de estilo Berkeley DB. Esta é uma camada de abstração geral para vários bancos de dados baseados em arquivos. Como tal, a funcionalidade é limitada a um subconjunto comum de recursos suportados por bancos de dados modernos, como o »Oracle Berkeley DB.
2. DBX

   > DBX: O módulo dbx é uma camada de banco de dados abstrata (db 'X', onde 'X' é o banco de dados suportado). As funções dbx permitem à você acessar todos os banco de dados suportados usando uma única convenção de chamada. As próprias funções-dbx não atuam diretamente com os bancos de dados, mas sim nos módulos que são usados para suportar estes banco de dados.
3. ODBC

   > ODBC: Em adição ao suporte ODBC normal, as funções de ODBC Unificadas no PHP permitem que você acesse vários bancos de dados que emprestaram a semântica da API do ODBC para implementer a sua própria API. Ao invés de manter múltiplos drivers de banco de dados que são todos praticamente identicos, estes drivers foram unificados em um único conjunto de funções ODBC. Os seguintes bancos de dados são suportados pelas funções de OBDC Unificado: » Adabas D, » IBM DB2, » iODBC, » Solid, e » Sybase SQL Anywhere.
4. PDO - PHP Data Objects

   > PDO: Cada driver de banco de dados que implementa a interface PDO pode expor recursos específicos do banco de dados como funções de extensão regulares. Observe que você não pode executar nenhuma função de banco de dados usando a extensão PDO por si só; Você deve usar um driver PDO específico do banco de dados para acessar um servidor de banco de dados. O PDO fornece uma camada de abstração de acesso a dados, o que significa que, independentemente do banco de dados que você está usando, você usa as mesmas funções para emitir consultas e buscar dados. O PDO não fornece uma abstração de banco de dados; Ele não reescreve o SQL ou simula recursos faltantes. Você deve usar uma camada de abstração completa se você precisar dessa facilidade. O PDO é fornecido com o PHP 5.1 e está disponível como uma extensão PECL para PHP 5.0; O PDO requer os novos recursos OO no núcleo do PHP 5 e, portanto, não será executado com versões anteriores do PHP.

Sobre as extensões de banco de dados específicas do fornecedor, a documentação cita 23 tipos e por serem extensas demais acredito que seja melhor dar uma olhada no link disponibilizado no início da resposta.

Answer (score -1):

Sim, o PHP pode se conectar a outros banco de dados como Oracle e etc, basta você pesquisar a documentação referente ao PHP. 
Segue aqui dois exemplos

- [SQL Server](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sqlsrv-connect.php)
- [Oracle](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.oci-new-connect.php)