# Consultar banco em outro servidor

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um banco de dados MySQL e preciso consultá-lo a partir de um outro servidor utilizando PHP. Qual a melhor maneira de se fazer isso?

É possível ativar uma função no servidor do banco e fazer com que ela retorne o resultado da consulta?

Answer (score 3):

Se o servidor mysql não tiver um firewall "de entrada" pode acessar normalmente com `mysqli` ou `PDO`, basta apontar o IP do *"servidor mysql"* ou o endereço de host dele (se tiver).

Exemplo com [`mysqli`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php):

```
<?php
$nomedoservidor = "mysql.outro-host.com";
$usuario = "username";
$senha = "password";
$banco = "banco1";

$conn = new mysqli($nomedoservidor, $usuario, $senha, $banco);
```

Se for um "ip fixo":

```
<?php
$nomedoservidor = "203.40.1.2"; //Exemplo fictício
$usuario = "username";
$senha = "password";
$banco = "banco1";

$conn = new mysqli($nomedoservidor, $usuario, $senha, $banco);
```

**Recomendo** que leia:

- [PHP somente se conecta com o MySQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/215080/3635)
- [Qual a diferença entre o MySQL e o phpMyAdmin?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115691/3635)
- [Qual diferença do Xampp, Wamp, EasyPHP, Zwamp e PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115689/3635)

Estas postagens vão lhe ajudar a entender aonde esta o servidor Mysql, aonde esta o PHP, aonde esta o Apache e o que é *Mysql API*.

Comment: O problema é que o servidor onde preciso usar os dados do banco não está aceitando PDO. Acho que provavelmente por conta de algum firewall.

Comment: @marcelo2605 qual erro exatamente?

Comment: ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on ENDEREÇO DO IP

Comment: @marcelo2605 você tem acesso ao painel para controle destes bancos externos?

Comment: A porta de acesso do mysql é a default : 3306? Verificou se está na porta correta? Experimentou dar ping sobre o ip do servidor aonde está o outro banco via DOS ou SHELL?