# PDO e mysqli são as únicas opções para trabalhar com banco de dados em PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

E se eu precisasse utilizar um banco de dados que não fosse suportado pelo PDO, o que eu poderia fazer?

Afinal de contas o que o PDO faz por baixo dos panos? Ele usa mysqli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao falarmos sobre **[extensões de bando de dados](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/refs.database.php)** voltado ao PHP, segundo a documentação, existem dois grupos distintos:

1. As camadas de abstrações, e;
2. Extensões de banco de dados específicas do fornecedor.

Referente as camadas de abstrações a documentação cita quatro tipos de camadas, ou seja, são quatro representações de conexão entre PHP e um servidor de banco de dados, são elas:

1. DBA - Database (dbm-style) Abstraction Layer

   > DBA: São funções que criam as bases para acessar os bancos de dados de estilo Berkeley DB. Esta é uma camada de abstração geral para vários bancos de dados baseados em arquivos. Como tal, a funcionalidade é limitada a um subconjunto comum de recursos suportados por bancos de dados modernos, como o »Oracle Berkeley DB.
2. DBX

   > DBX: O módulo dbx é uma camada de banco de dados abstrata (db 'X', onde 'X' é o banco de dados suportado). As funções dbx permitem à você acessar todos os banco de dados suportados usando uma única convenção de chamada. As próprias funções-dbx não atuam diretamente com os bancos de dados, mas sim nos módulos que são usados para suportar estes banco de dados.
3. ODBC

   > ODBC: Em adição ao suporte ODBC normal, as funções de ODBC Unificadas no PHP permitem que você acesse vários bancos de dados que emprestaram a semântica da API do ODBC para implementer a sua própria API. Ao invés de manter múltiplos drivers de banco de dados que são todos praticamente identicos, estes drivers foram unificados em um único conjunto de funções ODBC. Os seguintes bancos de dados são suportados pelas funções de OBDC Unificado: » Adabas D, » IBM DB2, » iODBC, » Solid, e » Sybase SQL Anywhere.
4. PDO - PHP Data Objects

   > PDO: Cada driver de banco de dados que implementa a interface PDO pode expor recursos específicos do banco de dados como funções de extensão regulares. Observe que você não pode executar nenhuma função de banco de dados usando a extensão PDO por si só; Você deve usar um driver PDO específico do banco de dados para acessar um servidor de banco de dados. O PDO fornece uma camada de abstração de acesso a dados, o que significa que, independentemente do banco de dados que você está usando, você usa as mesmas funções para emitir consultas e buscar dados. O PDO não fornece uma abstração de banco de dados; Ele não reescreve o SQL ou simula recursos faltantes. Você deve usar uma camada de abstração completa se você precisar dessa facilidade. O PDO é fornecido com o PHP 5.1 e está disponível como uma extensão PECL para PHP 5.0; O PDO requer os novos recursos OO no núcleo do PHP 5 e, portanto, não será executado com versões anteriores do PHP.

Sobre as extensões de banco de dados específicas do fornecedor, a documentação cita 23 tipos e por serem extensas demais acredito que seja melhor dar uma olhada no link disponibilizado no início da resposta.

Answer (score 3):

O PDO usa os mecanismos nativos dos bancos de dados para acessá-los. O PDO é só uma camada extra que provê pouca ou nenhuma vantagem em relação ao mecanismo original. Certamente há a desvantagem da camada extra.

Exceto pelo fato da maioria das pessoas usarem o PDO sem saber porque, elas só querem usar o que está na moda, elas o usam para que um dia possa trocar de banco de dados. Algo que normalmente nunca ocorre e quando ocorre, a pessoa descobre que não funciona tão simples assim, até fica compatível, mas não quer dizer que fica com bom desempenho.

É possível ter outros fornecedores do MySQL, mas não vejo ninguém usando.

É possível usar qualquer banco de dados que tenha um fornecedor, mesmo que não seja padrão do PHP. Há uma [pergunta que lista o que é padrão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215074/101).

É possível usar ODBC, mas na prática só fará isto se não tiver outro jeito. É melhor sempre procurar o acesso nativo ao banco de dados. Claro que o banco de dados deve poder se comunicar com ODBC. Em geral se o banco vale a pena sempre tem um acesso nativo.

Existem outros módulos que tentam abstrair o acesso como o PDO, mas não fazem sucesso. Nem sei bem porque, mas as pessoas não usam porque eles não resolvem um problema que não são resolvidos por outras solução.