# PHP: Como é o envio de e-mail via SMTP sem a função mail?

Tags: php, envio-de-email, smtp, cliente-servidor

Gostaria de saber como é a implementação de envio de e-mail com SMTP.

- Como é feita essa comunição se a função `mail` não é utilizada?
- Como é a comunicação com servidor nesse caso?
- Quais funções do PHP podem ser utilizadas para implementar isso?
- A comunicação é feita via socket? Como isso funciona?

PS: A questão não é sobre utilizar a biblioteca PHPMailer (ou outras bibliotecas de envio de e-mail), mas sim sobre a forma que é feito o envio e toda a comunicação que envolve isso dentro do PHP independente de bibliotecas. A duvida é mais conceitual e é sobre os porquês das escolhas de determinadas implementações.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como introdução, o que eu já disse nesta resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/215080/3635, estão *"sob o protocolo TCP"*, internamente a própria função `mail()` se conecta ao servidor SMTP padrão da hospedagem (isso pode ser ajustado no `php.ini`, mas o foco da pergunta não é este).

Então entendendo que quase tudo é escrito com base no TCP, o protocolo SMTP e IMAP não são exceções, então vamos separa primeiro os protocolos de e-mail:

- SMTP é um protocolo de envio de mensagens de email
- POP3 é um protocolo de recebimento/leitura de mensagens de email
- IMAP é um protocolo também de recebimento/leitura (claro que ambos são diferentes)

Então em php, assim como muitas linguagens, você pode fazer uma conexão a um servidor+porta, independente do serviço que a porta entregue, pode usar estas funções:

- `fsockopen()`
- `fsockopen()`
- `pfsockopen()`
- `stream_socket_client()`

Não vou detalhar uma por uma porque vai fugir do assunto. Basicamente o PHPMailer e outras bibliotecas semelhantes fazem basicamente isto:

```
$handler = fsockopen('smtp.servidor.com', 25);
```

Então ao estar conectado, neste momento você inicia um `while` que fica checando o "estado", assim:

```
while (feof($handler) === false) {
     ... ações ...
}
```

Então dentro do `while` você escreve e lê as respostas, o comando básico quando se conecta em um SMTP é `HELO` ou `EHLO` (o comando `EHLO` retorna mais detalhes, que as vezes são necessários dependendo do servidor), este comando é basicamente para pegar uma resposta simples e saber se isto é de fato um servidor SMTP, exemplo:

```
$dominio = 'smtp.servidor.com';
$handler = fsockopen($dominio, 25);

while (feof($handler) === false) {
     fwrite($handler, "HELO $dominio"); //Envia o seu comando

     $resposta = trim(fgets($handler)); //Pega a resposta

     if (strpos($resposta, '250') === 0) {
          //Esta no servidor SMTP
     } else {
         //NÃO esta no servidor SMTP
         break; //quebra o ciclo
     }
}

flose($handler);
```

Então estando tudo ok, você terá diversos comandos, para conectar em uma conta de email você poderá usar comandos como:

- `AUTH PLAIN`
- `AUTH LOGIN`
- `AUTH CRAM-MD5`

Nem todos servidor suporta/permite todos comandos, cada servidor é de usa uma forma de autenticação, geralmente o comando `EHLO` dá este detalhe no retorno da resposta, informando os suportados/permitidos.

Tudo isto você pode fazer até mesmo usando `telnet`, que é uma ferramenta de linha de comando (pode ser instalado em Windows também):

```
C:\Users\guilherme> telnet
Microsoft Telnet> OPEN smtp.servidor.com 25
250 smtp.servidor.com
HELO smtp.servidor.com
250-smtp.servidor.com
```

No exemplo acima o `OPEN` e o `HELO` eu digitei no cmd, as mensagens com numero com prefixo são respostas do servidor SMTP.

Isto porque é o que disse, é tudo via protocolos, até mesmo HTTP passa por algo semelhante e também é TCP.

> A algum tempo eu criei o meu próprio script de envio de email, tem muitos comandos que não me recordo, mas assim que encontrar o script irei detalhar a resposta com um exemplo de envio de email básico, caso contrário vou ler com calma sobre cada comando e elaborar um exemplo em breve.

Comment: Algumas perguntas mais específicas que fiz foram marcadas como duplicadas, no entanto ainda existem outras em aberto, se puder me ajudar com isso, agradeço.

Comment: Caro @rcs realmente eu tenho o tempo muito apertado, respondi a sua porque é um assunto que me interessa muito mesmo. Protocolos, historia de certas tecnologias e núcleos dos mesmos. Mas prometo olhar com calma todas suas perguntas.

Answer (score -7):

Exatamente como é feita, só você baixando a biblioteca e lendo código fonte. Nas documentações só vão dizer mesmo como fazer para funcionar e as funcionalidades. A função mail é uma função nativa do PHP, ela foi criada direto do código fonte do PHP feito em C. Se o PHPMailer não usa o mail é porque implementaram a própria função mail possivelmente por causa de alguma funcionalidade que o mail não proporcionava. Basta você entender como funciona o envio de email do tipo smtp (arquitetura, requests, etc) e refazer a lógica utilizando qualquer linguagem de programação.

Comment: Deixei meu voto contra porque a pergunta é basicamente "como funciona" e a resposta basicamente é "basta pesquisar como funciona". Ao meu ver não agregou muita coisa.

Comment: _Se o PHPMailer não usa o mail é porque implementaram a própria função mail possivelmente por causa de alguma funcionalidade que o mail não proporcionava._ A princípio, qual funcionalidade é essa que foi implementada? Como ela funciona? É esse o objetivo da pergunta.