# Para ter um banco no phpMyAdmin precisa do banco em Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, gostaria que me ajudassem em uma questão, meu código faz conexão com meu banco que esta no phpMyAdmin, e em alguns lugares que li, verifiquei que ele é um gerenciador de bancos. Minha pergunta e dúvida são exatamente a do título. É possível ter um banco em phpMyAdmin sem possuir um banco em Mysql?

Comment: [Essa resposta creio que responda isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115691/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-o-mysql-e-o-phpmyadmin/115692#115692). O PHPMyAdmin é apenas uma interface, que se conecta com um banco de dados, tal como o HeidiSQL, por exemplo. O PHPMyAdmin não faz nada, apenas exibe de maneira "mais fácil" para você. O PHPMyAdmin NUNCA vai ter um "banco", quem tem é banco de dados no qual ele está conectado.

Comment: Como eu consigo ligar então o phpMyAdmin com o Mysql?

Comment: @Alis voce esta usando o que? MAMP, XAMP, EASYPHP, WAMPSERVER?

Comment: estou usando o WampServer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É preciso entender que o PHPMyadmin não é uma linguagem SQL, e sim uma interface para manipulação da linguagem SQL (No caso Mysql).

MySQL é outra coisa bem diferente, não é o painel, mas sim um SGBD. O MySQL que é o banco de dados, não o PHPMyAdmin.

Pense em um médico, ele não é um remédio, mas é o meio para se chegar ao remédio.

O PHPMyAdmin não é o banco de dados, mas é o meio para se chegar ao banco de dados.

#### Logo, a resposta a sua pergunta:

**Não é possível ter o PHPMyAdmin sem MySQL.** Mas é possível ter MySQL sem o PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: O MySQL não é uma linguagem, é um "sistema gerenciador de base de dados relacionais" (SGBD/RDBMS).

Comment: MUITOOOO.. obrigada.. realmente.. obrigadaaa