# Como enviar dados de uma página HTML para o MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Eu fiz um formulário de cadastro, porém ao mandar os valores para o banco de dados, ele não preenche a tabela e não retorna nenhum erro.

Código que usei foi o seguinte:

```
<body>
    <?php
        $conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","villadobem")
    ?>

    <?php 
    // RECEBENDO OS DADOS PREENCHIDOS DO FORMULÁRIO !
    $nome   = $_POST ["nome"];
    $data   = $_POST ["data"];
    $sexo   = $_POST ["sexo"];
    $email  = $_POST ["email"];
    $email2 = $_POST ["email2"];
    $senha  = $_POST ["senha"];
    $senha1 = $_POST ["senha1"];
    $cpf    = $_POST ["cpf"];
    $tel    = $_POST ["tel"];
    $cel    = $_POST ["cel"];
    $cep    = $_POST ["cep"];
    $rua    = $_POST ["rua"];
    $numero = $_POST ["numero"];
    $bairro = $_POST ["bairro"];
    $cidade = $_POST ["cidade"];
    $uf     = $_POST ["uf"];
    $instituiçao    = $_POST ["instituição"];
    $nivel  = $_POST ["nivel"];
    $curso  = $_POST ["curso"];
    $area   = $_POST ["area"];
    $turno  = $_POST ["turno"];
    $palestras  = $_POST ["palestras"];
    $cidade2    = $_POST ["cidade2"];

    if(!empty($_POST['dias']) && count($_POST['dias']) ){
       $chgeckboxes = $_POST['dias'];
       print_r($chgeckboxes);
       //implode
       $dias = implode(',', $_POST['dias']);
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['hora']) && count($_POST['hora']) ){
       $chgeckboxes = $_POST['hora'];
       print_r($chgeckboxes);
       //implode
       $hora = implode(',', $_POST['hora']);
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['Habilidades']) && count($_POST['Habilidades']) ){
       $chgeckboxes = $_POST['Habilidades'];
       print_r($chgeckboxes);
       //implode
       $habilidades = implode(',', $_POST['Habilidades']);

    //rotina para gravação no DB

    }
    //Gravando no banco de dados !
    mysqli_query($conexao, "insert into voluntários (nome, data, sexo, email, email2, senha, senha1, cpf, tel, cel, cep, rua, numero, bairro, cidade, uf, instituição, nivel, curso, area, turno, dias, hora, habilidades, palestras, cidade2) values ('$nome', '$data', '$sexo', '$email', '$email2', '$senha', '$senha1', '$cpf', '$tel', '$cel', '$cep', '$rua', '$numero', '$bairro', '$cidade', '$uf', '$instituiçao', '$nivel', '$curso', '$area', '$turno', '$dias', '$hora', '$habilidades', '$palestras', '$cidade2')");
    ?>
</body>
```

O que pode estar errado?

Comment: Você checou com [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)? E tem variável com cedilha e nome de tabela com acento, é isso mesmo? Pode até ser aceito, mas eu não arriscaria.

Comment: Era a cedilha e o acento mesmo, tirei ai deu certo, muito obrigado, ajudou demais!!

Comment: phpmyadmin não tem relação qualquer direta com tua aplicação, ele é apenas uma ferramenta de gerenciamento extra, que pode ser facilmente substituido por outras ferramentas semelhante, no entanto o banco continua sendo o mesmo, dê uma lida nisto apenas por curiosidade: [*Qual a diferença entre o MySQL e o phpMyAdmin?*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115691/3635)

Answer (score 1):

Sempre faça o escape dos dados que você quer enviar no SQL... previne o erros em relação a acentuação e caracteres especiais.

```
mysqli_query($conexao, "insert into `voluntários` (`nome`, `data`, `sexo`, ...
```

Não está no seu problema, mas eu queria deixar uma dica aqui pra você bem bacana, pra você evitar muitas linhas. Que é a função `extract`

```
<?php
  extract($_POST);
  /* esse carinha vai fazer isso aqui pra você:
    $nome   = $_POST ["nome"];
    $data   = $_POST ["data"];
    $sexo   = $_POST ["sexo"];

    Ele converte a sua chave do array em variável
  */
```

Comment: Não é necessário tal alteração

Answer (score 0):

Ao inserir dados é importante ter em mente o tipo do dado que você está inserindo.

`1` é diferente de `'1'`.
`1` é um valor numérico, e `'1'` é uma string (Um texto).

Vamos supor o seguinte exemplo:

```
Tabela Exemplo(
Id int,
Nome varchar(100),
data date
)
```

Ao inserir dados nela fariamos da seguinte forma:

```
insert into Exemplo (id, nome, date) values ($id, '$nome', '$date')
```

**Note**: O Campo `Nome` e `Data` são inseridos entre aspas simples pois estes campos são inseridos no banco de dados como String. Já o `id` não necessita, pois é um campo inteiro.