# Como configurar tempo maximo de importação no phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

estou fazendo uma aplicação e preciso fazer um import de um arquivo sql muito grande no phpmyadmin e recebo o seguinte erro:

****Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in E:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Dbal\DbiMysqli.php on line 209****

ja configurei max execution time em php.ini para 600, reiniciei e continuo a receber o msm erro

estou usando a instalação do xampp com php 7.4

Answer (score 1):

O phpMyAdmin, fora ser necessário configurar o php.ini, também precisa que configure um arquivo próprio, o `config.default.php`. Para localiza-lo vá na instalação do Xampp e procure a pasta do *phpMyAdmin*, procure dentro dela o arquivo:

```
.../phpMyAdmin/libraries/config.default.php
```

> **Não** confunda com o `.../phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`

No arquivo `config.default.php`, procure por `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit']` e altere para:

```
/**
 * maximum execution time in seconds (0 for no limit)
 *
 * @global integer $cfg['ExecTimeLimit']
 */
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 600;
```

Comment: Note que o [phpMyAdmin não é obrigatório para que o seu mysql funcione](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115692/3635), ele é só uma ferramenta extra, existem softwares que talvez possam lhe atender melhor, algumas sugestões [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) e [dbBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/).